# jQuery: checking if the value of a field is null (empty)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is this a good way to check if the value of a field is `null`?

```
if($('#person_data[document_type]').value() != 'NULL'){}
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: what kind of element is #person_data? and what do you consider as a NULL value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49923589/7186739

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The value of a field can not be null, it's always a string value.

The code will check if the string value is the string "NULL". You want to check if it's an empty string instead:

```
if ($('#person_data[document_type]').val() != ''){}
```

or:

```
if ($('#person_data[document_type]').val().length != 0){}
```

If you want to check if the element exist at all, you should do that before calling `val`:

```
var $d = $('#person_data[document_type]');
if ($d.length != 0) {
  if ($d.val().length != 0 ) {...}
}
```

Comment: `The value of a field can not be null, it's always a string value.` this isn't entirely true. I've got a `select` containing no `options`. When I perform `.val()` on this it returns `null`. Jquery 1.7.2

Comment: @Pispirulito: I don't think so, and I don't think that it will be changed. A `select` without any `option` elements is not something that you normally have. It's pretty useless.

Comment: @Guffa beg to differ, an empty `<select>` can contain possible options for your user whose `<option>`s will come from some sort of validation.

Comment: If you use the following solution to provide a placeholder in your `select`, it will start out with a `null` value because a 'disabled' option is selected. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box

Comment: This worked for me not equal null `if ($('#person_data[document_type]').val() !== null){}`

Answer (score 38):

I would also trim the input field, cause a space could make it look like filled

```
if ($.trim($('#person_data[document_type]').val()) != '')
{

}
```

Answer (score 17):

Assuming

```
var val = $('#person_data[document_type]').value();
```

you have these cases:

```
val === 'NULL';  // actual value is a string with content "NULL"
val === '';      // actual value is an empty string
val === null;    // actual value is null (absence of any value)
```

So, use what you need.

Answer (score 15):

that depends on what kind of information are you passing to the conditional..

sometimes your result will be `null` or `undefined` or `''` or `0`, for my simple validation i use this if.

```
( $('#id').val() == '0' || $('#id').val() == '' || $('#id').val() == 'undefined' || $('#id').val() == null )
```

**NOTE**: `null` != `'null'`

Answer (score 8):

```
_helpers: {
        //Check is string null or empty
        isStringNullOrEmpty: function (val) {
            switch (val) {
                case "":
                case 0:
                case "0":
                case null:
                case false:
                case undefined:
                case typeof this === 'undefined':
                    return true;
                default: return false;
            }
        },

        //Check is string null or whitespace
        isStringNullOrWhiteSpace: function (val) {
            return this.isStringNullOrEmpty(val) || val.replace(/\s/g, "") === '';
        },

        //If string is null or empty then return Null or else original value
        nullIfStringNullOrEmpty: function (val) {
            if (this.isStringNullOrEmpty(val)) {
                return null;
            }
            return val;
        }
    },
```

Utilize this helpers to achieve that.

Comment: this almost seems like `isStringNullOrEmpty` is `isStringFalsey` and thus `return !val;` would work

Answer (score 0):

jquery provides `val()` function and `not value()`. You can check empty string using jquery

```
if($('#person_data[document_type]').val() != ''){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
if( this["person_data[document_type]"].value != '') { 
  console.log('not empty');
}
```

```html
<input id="person_data[document_type]" value="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My Working solution is

```
var town_code = $('#town_code').val(); 
 if(town_code.trim().length == 0){
    var town_code = 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `'NULL'` is a string. So its wrong.

You can use exclamation mark `!` to check if it is null.

Here is the code:

```
if(!$('#person_data[document_type]').val()){

}
```

The above code means that if the `$('#person_data[document_type]')` has no value (if the value is null).