# How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?

Tags: html, css, html-select, placeholder

I'm using placeholders for text inputs which is working out just fine. But I'd like to use a placeholder for my selectboxes as well. Of course I can just use this code:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Select your option</option>
    <option value="hurr">Durr</option>
</select>
```

But the 'Select your option' is in black instead of lightgrey. So my solution could possibly be CSS-based. jQuery is fine too.

This only makes the option grey in the dropdown (so after clicking the arrow):

```css
option:first {
    color: #999;
}
```

The question is: How do people create placeholders in selectboxes? But it has already been answered, cheers.

And using this results in the selected value always being grey (even after selecting a real option):

```css
select {
    color: #999;
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that if you want your form to be accessible then the best course of action is probably to put the placeholder in a `label` element beside the dropdown.

Comment: This is 2023, why HTML doesn't have a placeholder for select boxes?

Answer (score 3742, accepted):

A non-CSS - no JavaScript/jQuery answer:

```html
<label>Option name
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="hurr">Durr</option>
</select>
</label>
```

**Update** (December 2021):

This works for latest Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. It used to not work for many browsers in the past, as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Once the user has selected a value, he can not deselect again (even when the select value is optional)!

Comment: @PoulBak I think in most ux contexts this is actually preferred.

Comment: I personally don't like this solution because you can't remove your selection by reselecting the "placeholder"-option.

Comment: If you're using React you might get the following Warning: 
`use the 'defaultvalue' or 'value' props on <select> instead of setting 'selected' on <option>`.
To remove that warning, you would remove `selected` from `<option>` and instead on `<select>` add the attribute `defaultValue='default'` then on `<option>` add `value='default'` for the option you want shown by default.  Both values in value and defaultValue must match up.

Comment: @KevinGlier You can do that with a reset button, which would better anyway than trying to manually reset all your individual fields in a form.

Comment: It's submittable. So unless you don't want to get an error, it's not really a "no JS" solution

Comment: Only use this for _required_ boxes, if a box is not required remove the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: This solution looks nice, but is not very accessible, as `disabled` breaks keyboard navigation. The solution from @Dani-Br works great with keyboard.

Comment: using this in editable forms looks not reliable

Answer (score 1118):

Here's what works in Firefox and Chrome (at least):

```html
<style>
select:invalid { color: gray; }
</style>
<form>
<select required>
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
    <option value="0">Open when powered (most valves do this)</option>
    <option value="1">Closed when powered, auto-opens when power is cut</option>
</select>
</form>
```

The *disabled* attribute stops the `<option>` from being selected with either mouse or keyboard; if you just used `'display:none'`, it allows the user to select it via keyboard navigation.

Using an empty `value` attribute on the "placeholder" option allows validation (via the `required` attribute) to work around having the "placeholder", so if the option isn't changed, but is required, the browser should prompt the user to choose an option from the list.

When the `select` element has the `required` attribute, it allows use of the `:invalid` CSS pseudo-class which allows you to style the `select` element when in its "placeholder" state. `:invalid` works here because of the empty value in the placeholder `option`.

Once a value has been set, the `:invalid` pseudo-class will be dropped. You can optionally also use `:valid` if you so wish.

This works best with custom styled `select` elements; in some cases i.e. (Mac in Chrome / Safari) you'll need to change the default appearance of the `select` box so that certain styles display, i.e., `background-color` and `color`. You can find some examples and more about compatibility at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid).

Native element appearance Mac in Chrome:

[image: Select box native Mac in Chrome]

Using altered border element Mac in Chrome:

[image: Altered select box Mac in Chrome]

Comment: The options in the dropdown are grey for me until after I select one.

Comment: This isn't working 100% as expected. The select dropdown options are displayed in gray when opened for the first time. Chrome on Windows 10, which is weird. I suggest adding also this style to avoid that `select option { color: black; }`

Answer (score 335):

For a required field, there is a pure-CSS solution in modern browsers:

```css
select:required:invalid {
  color: gray;
}
option[value=""][disabled] {
  display: none;
}
option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select something...</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is the placeholder submittable here?

Comment: @Sergey It is, since it is an option like any other.

Answer (score 118):

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<select id="choice">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Something</option>
    <option value="2">Something else</option>
    <option value="3">Another choice</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```css
#choice option { color: black; }
.empty { color: gray; }
```

JavaScript:

```js
$("#choice").change(function () {
  if($(this).val() == "0") $(this).addClass("empty");
  else $(this).removeClass("empty")
});
    
$("#choice").change();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmf6t/

Comment: This works fine, when the select value is optional, the user can deselect again.

Answer (score 71):

I just added a hidden attribute in an `option` like below. It is working fine for me.

```html
<select>
  <option hidden>Sex</option>
  <option>Male</option>
  <option>Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Once the user has selected a value, he can not deselect again (even when the select value is optional)!

Comment: @PoulBak You should do this if the dropdown is *required*, so you have to select one of the available values.

Answer (score 50):

The solution below works without any JavaScript:

```css
option[default] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="" default selected>Select Your Age</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

It hides the default option once you've selected a different one, so you won't be able to re-select the default option afterward.

Answer (score 29):

Here is a good solution that worked for me:

HTML:

```
<select class="place_holder dropdown">
    <option selected="selected" style=" display: none;">Sort by</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>something</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```css
.place_holder {
    color: gray;
}
option {
    color: #000000;
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```js
jQuery(".dropdown").change(function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("place_holder");
});
```

After the customer makes the first select, there isn't any need for gray color, so the JavaScript code removes the class `place_holder`.

As a workaround for Internet Explorer, you can add the `place_holder` class again in case the first option is selected again.

Answer (score 29):

There isn't any need for any JavaScript or CSS, just three attributes:

```
<select>
    <option selected disabled hidden>Default Value</option>
    <option>Value 1</option>
    <option>Value 2</option>
    <option>Value 3</option>
    <option>Value 4</option>
</select>
```

It doesn't show the option at all; it just sets the option's value as the default.

However, if you just **don't like a placeholder that's the same color as the rest**, you can fix it inline like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Placeholder for select tag drop-down menu</title>
    </head>

    <body onload="document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex = 0">
        <select id="mySelect" onchange="document.getElementById('mySelect').style.color = 'black'"     style="color: gray;    width: 150px;">
          <option value="" hidden>Select your beverage</option> <!-- placeholder -->
          <option value="water" style="color:black" >Water</option>
          <option value="milk" style="color:black" >Milk</option>
          <option value="soda" style="color:black" >Soda</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, you can separated the functions and at least the select's CSS into separate files.

**Note:** the onload function corrects a refresh bug.

Answer (score 25):

The user should not see the placeholder in select options. I suggest to use the `hidden` attribute for the placeholder option, and you don't need the `selected` attribute for this option. You can just put it as the first.

```css
select:not(:valid) {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<select required>
    <option value="" hidden>Select your option</option>
    <option value="0">First option</option>
    <option value="1">Second option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Once the user has selected a value, he can not deselect again (even when the select value is optional)!

Answer (score 21):

1. `selected` makes the particular option selected on page load
2. `disabled` ensures the option is excluded in the form submission
3. `hidden` visually hides the option in the dropdown list

```html
    <select>
        <option selected disabled hidden>Choose an Option</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should provide some context to explain how your answer differs from the accepted one

Comment: it's using only a select tag without any JQuery and CSS . use attribute Disabled , selected & hidden

Comment: The point is to help someone who is not aware about these attributes. Usually it is not well accepted on Stack Overflow an answer that just dump code without explanations.

Answer (score 19):

```css
select:focus option.holder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option selected="selected" class="holder">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Option #1</option>
    <option value="2">Option #2</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 19):

Here I have modified [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box/5859221#5859221) (accepted answer). On his answer, he put disabled and selected attribute on the `option` tag, but when we also put hidden tag then it will look much better.

By adding an extra hidden attribute on the `option` tag, it will prevent the "Select your option" option from being re-selecting after the "Durr" option is selected.

```html
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select your option</option>
    <option value="hurr">Durr</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 14):

I see signs of correct answers, but to bring it all together, this would be my solution:

```css
select {
  color: grey;
}

option {
  color: black;
}

option[default] {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="" default selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="hurr">Durr</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 12):

There is Cool property in HTML and you can use it to create a Placeholder for select attribute
In my case I am using following code and you can change it according to your requirements

```
 <select ref={relationship} required className="sellertype">
          <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Your Seller Type</option>
          <option value="1">Importer</option>
          <option value="2">Exporter</option>
          <option value="3">Local Seller</option>
          <option value="4">Local Buyer</option>
        </select>
```

Now "Select your Seller Type" will work as a placeholder

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Angular, go like this:

```html
<select>
    <option [ngValue]="undefined"  disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option [ngValue]="hurr">Durr</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 9):

This HTML + CSS solution worked for me:

```css
form select:invalid {
  color: gray;
}

form select option:first-child {
  color: gray;
}

form select:invalid option:not(:first-child) {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select required>
    <option value="">Select Planet...</option>
    <option value="earth">Earth</option>
    <option value="pandora">Pandora</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: this seems the best solution to me, but what if you don't want the field required, but optional... ?

Answer (score 9):

You could set the first option's color to `gray`, set it's display to `none`, set the `select`'s color to `gray`, and add an `input` event listener to it that sets it's color to `black`.

```css
select > option:not(:first-of-type) {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select style='color:gray' oninput='style.color="black"'>
  <option style='display:none'>
    Choose an option
  </option>
  <option>
    1
  </option>
  <option>
    2
  </option>
  <option>
    3
  </option>
</select>
```

Using the `customElement` API:

```js
class placeholderSelect extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `<select style='color:gray' oninput='style.color="black"'>
  <option style='display:none'>
    ${this.getAttribute('data-placeholder')}
  </option>
  ${this.innerHTML}
</select>`;

    Array.from(this.children[0].children).forEach(function(el, i) {
        el.style.color = 'black';
    });
  }
}

customElements.define('placeholder-select', placeholderSelect);
```

```html
<placeholder-select data-placeholder='Choose an option'>
  <option>
    1
  </option>
  <option>
    2
  </option>
  <option>
    3
  </option>
</placeholder-select>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is now possible with CSS only.

You can use the new `:has()` selector to activate placeholder styles on the select whenever an option with an empty value is selected.

This matches how text inputs show placeholders when they are empty.

```html
<select>
  <option value="">Please choose...</option>
  <option value="a">Option 1</option>
  <option value="b">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

```css
select {
  color: black;
}

select:has(option[value=""]:checked) {
  color: gray;
}
```

This select box will show `Please choose...` in gray, and will change to black when either of the other two options are selected.

This solution allows the `Please choose...` option to be reselected to clear the select and set its value to `""` empty string.

In a `required` select box, you might also wish to hide the empty option from the list so it cannot be reselected:

```css
select:required option[value=""] {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I consider this the best answer by far!

Comment: This will render all options in select dropdown as grey when the first is selected. YOu need your css to have select option { color: black; } for this to override this look for the dropdown options.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility in JavaScript:

```
 $('body').on('change', 'select', function (ev){
    if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == ""){
        $(this).css('color', '#999');
        $(this).children().css('color', 'black');
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('color', 'black');
        $(this).children().css('color', 'black');
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rgDb/)

Answer (score 7):

Solution for 2023 with `:has` selector:

```css
select:has(option:disabled:checked[hidden]) {
  color: gray;
}

select option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected disabled hidden>Choose</option>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is a great comment for 2023! The following modification allows the `<select>` to show a placeholder style whenever the select has an empty value, similar to how a `<input type="text">` works. 

This allows you to select an option that effectively clears the `<select>`

`select:has(option[value=""]:checked)`

Answer (score 6):

#### Input `[type="text"]` Style Placeholder for Select Elements

The following solution simulates a placeholder as it relates to an `input[type="text"]` element:

```js
$('.example').change(function () {
  $(this).css('color', $(this).val() === '' ? '#999' : '#555');
});
```

```css
.example {
  color: #999;
}

.example > option {
  color: #555;
}

.example > option[value=""] {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="example">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

Building upon [MattW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806043/3317167), you can make the select placeholder option visible in the drop-down menu after a valid selection has been made, by conditionally hiding it only while the placeholder remains selected (and the select is therefore :invalid).

```css
select:required:invalid {
  color: gray;
}
select:invalid > option[value=""][disabled] {
  display: none;
}
option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select something...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

This works well for me:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="" readonly="true" hidden="true" selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1">Something</option>
    <option value="2">Something else</option>
    <option value="3">Another choice</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

I wanted the SELECT to be grey until selected so for this piece of HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
  <option value="hurr">Durr</option>
</select>
```

I've added these CSS definitions:

```
select { color: grey; }
select:valid { color: black; }
```

It works as expected in Chrome / Safari and maybe also in other browsers, but I haven't checked.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a **CSS** solution that works beautifully. The content is added (and absolutely positioned relative to the container) after the containing element (**via :after pseudo-class**).

It gets its text from the placeholder attribute that I defined where I used the directive (**attr(placeholder)**). Another key factor is **pointer-events: none** - this allows clicks on the placeholder text to pass through to the select. Otherwise it won't drop down if the user clicks the text.

I add the **.empty** class myself in my select directive, but normally I find that angular adds/removes **.ng-empty** for me (I assume it's because I'm injecting version 1.2 of Angular in my code sample).

*(The sample also demonstrates how to wrap HTML elements in AngularJS to create your own custom inputs)*

```js
var app = angular.module("soDemo", []);
app.controller("soDemoController", function($scope) {
  var vm = {};
  vm.names = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Jon'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Joe'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Bob'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Jane'
    }
  ];
  vm.nameId;
  $scope.vm = vm;
});

app.directive('soSelect', function soSelect() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      'valueProperty': '@',
      'displayProperty': '@',
      'modelProperty': '=',
      'source': '=',
    },
    link: link,
    template: getTemplate
  };
  return directive;


  /////////////////////////////////
  function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
    init();
    return;


    ///////////// IMPLEMENTATION

    function init() {
      initDataBinding();
    }


    function initDataBinding() {
      ngModelController.$render = function() {
        if (scope.model === ngModelController.$viewValue) return;
        scope.model = ngModelController.$viewValue;
      }

      scope.$watch('model', function(newValue) {
        if (newValue === undefined) {
          element.addClass('empty');
          return;
        }
        element.removeClass('empty');
        ngModelController.$setViewValue(newValue);
      });
    }
  }


  function getTemplate(element, attrs) {
    var attributes = [
      'ng-model="model"',
      'ng-required="true"'
    ];

    if (angular.isDefined(attrs.placeholder)) {
      attributes.push('placeholder="{{placeholder}}"');
    }

    var ngOptions = '';

    if (angular.isDefined(attrs.valueProperty)) {
      ngOptions += 'item.' + attrs.valueProperty + ' as ';
    }

    ngOptions += 'item.' + attrs.displayProperty + ' for item in source';
    ngOptions += '"';
    attributes.push('ng-options="' + ngOptions + '"');

    var html = '<select ' + attributes.join(' ') + '></select>';

    return html;
  }
});
```

```css
so-select {
  position: relative;
}

so-select select {
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #222;
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

so-select.empty:before {
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-size: 12px;
  content: attr(placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 6px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 0;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="soDemo" ng-controller="soDemoController">
  <so-select value-property="id" display-property="name" source="vm.names" ng-model="vm.nameId" placeholder="(select name)"></so-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get any of these to work currently, because for me it is (1) not required and (2) need the option to return to default selectable. So here's a heavy handed option if you are using jQuery:

```js
var $selects = $('select');
$selects.change(function () {
  var option = $('option:default', this);
  if(option && option.is(':selected')) {
    $(this).css('color', '#999');
  }
  else {
    $(this).css('color', '#555');
  }
});

$selects.each(function() {
  $(this).change();
});
```

```css
option {
    color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="in-op">
    <option default selected>Select Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery validation for the form, you can still set the `required` attribute on the `select` field to take advantage of the `:invalid` CSS while also adding an `ignore` class to it and then configuring the `ignore` property in the `validate()` options (see https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not content with HTML/CSS-only solutions, so I've decided to create a custom `select` using JavaScript.

This is something I've written in the past 30 mins, thus it can be further improved.

All you have to do is create a simple list with few data attributes. The code automatically turns the list into a selectable dropdown. It also adds a hidden `input` to hold the selected value, so it can be used in a form.

Input:

```
<ul class="select" data-placeholder="Role" data-name="role">
  <li data-value="admin">Administrator</li>
  <li data-value="mod">Moderator</li>
  <li data-value="user">User</li>
</ul>
```

Output:

```
<div class="ul-select-container">
    <input type="hidden" name="role" class="hidden">
    <div class="selected placeholder">
        <span class="text">Role</span>
        <span class="icon">▼</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="select" data-placeholder="Role" data-name="role">
        <li class="placeholder">Role</li>
        <li data-value="admin">Administrator</li>
        <li data-value="mod">Moderator</li>
        <li data-value="user">User</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The text of the item that's supposed to be a placeholder is grayed out. The placeholder is selectable, in case the user wants to revert his/her choice. Also using CSS, all the drawbacks of `select` can be overcome (e.g., inability of the styling of the options).

```js
// Helper function to create elements faster/easier
// https://github.com/akinuri/js-lib/blob/master/element.js
var elem = function(tagName, attributes, children, isHTML) {
  let parent;
  if (typeof tagName == "string") {
    parent = document.createElement(tagName);
  } else if (tagName instanceof HTMLElement) {
    parent = tagName;
  }
  if (attributes) {
    for (let attribute in attributes) {
      parent.setAttribute(attribute, attributes[attribute]);
    }
  }
  var isHTML = isHTML || null;
  if (children || children == 0) {
    elem.append(parent, children, isHTML);
  }
  return parent;
};
elem.append = function(parent, children, isHTML) {
  if (parent instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement || parent instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
    if (children instanceof Text || typeof children == "string" || typeof children == "number") {
      parent.value = children;
    } else if (children instanceof Array) {
      children.forEach(function(child) {
        elem.append(parent, child);
      });
    } else if (typeof children == "function") {
      elem.append(parent, children());
    }
  } else {
    if (children instanceof HTMLElement || children instanceof Text) {
      parent.appendChild(children);
    } else if (typeof children == "string" || typeof children == "number") {
      if (isHTML) {
        parent.innerHTML += children;
      } else {
        parent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(children));
      }
    } else if (children instanceof Array) {
      children.forEach(function(child) {
        elem.append(parent, child);
      });
    } else if (typeof children == "function") {
      elem.append(parent, children());
    }
  }
};


// Initialize all selects on the page
$("ul.select").each(function() {
  var parent    = this.parentElement;
  var refElem   = this.nextElementSibling;
  var container = elem("div", {"class": "ul-select-container"});
  var hidden    = elem("input", {"type": "hidden", "name": this.dataset.name, "class": "hidden"});
  var selected  = elem("div", {"class": "selected placeholder"}, [
    elem("span", {"class": "text"}, this.dataset.placeholder),
    elem("span", {"class": "icon"}, "&#9660;", true),
  ]);
  var placeholder = elem("li", {"class": "placeholder"}, this.dataset.placeholder);
  this.insertBefore(placeholder, this.children[0]);
  container.appendChild(hidden);
  container.appendChild(selected);
  container.appendChild(this);
  parent.insertBefore(container, refElem);
});

// Update necessary elements with the selected option
$(".ul-select-container ul li").on("click", function() {
  var text     = this.innerText;
  var value    = this.dataset.value || "";
  var selected = this.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
  var hidden   = selected.previousElementSibling;
  hidden.value = selected.dataset.value = value;
  selected.children[0].innerText = text;
  if (this.classList.contains("placeholder")) {
    selected.classList.add("placeholder");
  } else {
    selected.classList.remove("placeholder");
  }
  selected.parentElement.classList.remove("visible");
});

// Open select dropdown
$(".ul-select-container .selected").on("click", function() {
  if (this.parentElement.classList.contains("visible")) {
    this.parentElement.classList.remove("visible");
  } else {
    this.parentElement.classList.add("visible");
  }
});

// Close select when focus is lost
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  var container = $(e.target).closest(".ul-select-container");
  if (container.length == 0) {
    $(".ul-select-container.visible").removeClass("visible");
  }
});
```

```css
.ul-select-container {
  width: 200px;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.ul-select-container.visible ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.ul-select-container ul {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 60%);
  border-top: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
.ul-select-container ul li {
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
.ul-select-container ul li.placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.ul-select-container ul li:hover {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
.ul-select-container ul li.placeholder:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: initial;
}
.ul-select-container .selected {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px 10px 4px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 60%);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.ul-select-container .selected {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.ul-select-container .selected.placeholder .text {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.ul-select-container .selected .icon {
  font-size: .7em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.ul-select-container:hover .selected {
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 30%);
}
.ul-select-container:hover .selected .icon {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="select" data-placeholder="Role" data-name="role">
  <li data-value="admin">Administrator</li>
  <li data-value="mod">Moderator</li>
  <li data-value="user">User</li>
</ul>

<ul class="select" data-placeholder="Sex" data-name="sex">
  <li data-value="male">Male</li>
  <li data-value="female">Female</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Update**: I've improved this (selection using up/down/enter keys), tidied up the output a little bit, and turned this into a object. Current output:

```
<div class="li-select-container">
    <input type="text" readonly="" placeholder="Role" title="Role">
    <span class="arrow">▼</span>
    <ul class="select">
        <li class="placeholder">Role</li>
        <li data-value="admin">Administrator</li>
        <li data-value="mod">Moderator</li>
        <li data-value="user">User</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Initialization:

```
new Liselect(document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]);
```

For further examination:  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtxvsu14/9/), [<strike>GitHub</strike>](https://github.com/akinuri/js-lib/tree/master/liselect) (renamed).

---

**Update:** I am have rewritten this again. Instead of using a list, we can just use a select. This way it'll work even without JavaScript (in case it's disabled).

Input:

```
<select name="role" data-placeholder="Role" required title="Role">
    <option value="admin">Administrator</option>
    <option value="mod">Moderator</option>
    <option>User</option>
</select>
```

```
new Advancelect(document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0]);
```

Output:

```
<div class="advanced-select">
    <input type="text" readonly="" placeholder="Role" title="Role" required="" name="role">
    <span class="arrow">▼</span>
    <ul>
        <li class="placeholder">Role</li>
        <li data-value="admin">Administrator</li>
        <li data-value="mod">Moderator</li>
        <li>User</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtxvsu14/12/), [GitHub](https://github.com/akinuri/js-lib/tree/master/Advancelect).

Answer (score 5):

I love [the accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box/5859221#5859221), and it works great without JavaScript.

I just want to add how I adopted this answer for a **controlled-select React Component**, because it took me a few tries to figure it out. It would be really simple to incorporate `react-select` and be done with it, but unless you need the amazing functionality this repository provides, which I don't for the project in question, there is no need to add any more kilobytes to my bundle. Note, `react-select` handles placeholders in selects through a complex system of various `inputs` and `html` elements.

In React, for a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), you cannot add the `selected` attribute to your options. React handles the state of the select via a `value` attribute upon the `select` itself, along with a change handler, where the value should match one of the value attributes within the options themselves.

Such as, for example

```
<select value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.handleChange} required={true}>
    {options}
</select>
```

Since it would be improper and in fact would throw an error to add the `selected` attribute to one of the options, what then?

The answer is simple once you think about it. Since we want our first `option` to be `selected` as well as `disabled` and `hidden`, we need to do three things:

1. Add the `hidden` and `disabled` attribute to the first defined `option`.
2. Set the value of the first `option` to be an empty string.
3. Initialize the value of the `select` to also be an empty string.

```html
state = { selectValue = "" } // State or props or their equivalent

// In the render function
<select value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.handleChange} required={true}>
    <option key="someKey" value="" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden">Select from Below</option>
    {renderOptions()}
</select>
```

Now you can style the select as indicated above (or via a `className` if you prefer).

```
select:invalid { color: gray; }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need form validation and modern browsers offer this from scratch.

So you do not need to take care that the user can not select the field. Because when he is doing it, the browser validation will tell him, that this is a wrong selection.

The browser built in validation function [checkValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity).

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#validation) has there a nice example as well.

**HTML**

```
<form class="needs-validation">
  <select required>
    <option value="">Please select an option</option>
    <option value="1">Foo</option>
    <option value="2">Bar</option>
  </select>
<form>
```

**Javascript**

```
form = document.getElementByClassName('needs-validation');
if(form.checkValidity() === true) {
  //form validation succeeded
} else {
  //form validation failed
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without using JavaScript and using only HTML You need to set the default select option `disabled=""` and `selected=""` and select tag `required="".` Browsers don't allow the user to submit the form without selecting an option.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name="in-op" required="">
        <option disabled="" selected="">Select Option</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Because of the diverse styling and functionality between answers provided in this thread, the table of below clarifies the styling and applicable form logic for each of the HTML, HTML+CSS and HTML+CSS+Javascript solutions provided.

I've had to use code formatting because [tables aren't permitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) in markup, for some reason.
A HTML table will be provided using the code snippet to work around the table restriction.

I've marked this post as `community wiki` so anyone can detail new posts, though please add JQuery, React, Angular, CoffeeScript, etc, to an alternate post to keep this table simple.

```
         | Technologies |                                                                Styling                                                                |
  Post   | CSS | Java-  | Select: Placeholder |  Select: valid option  |                  Option: placeholder                    |     Option: valid option     |
   ID    |     | script | Color |  Validation | Color |    Required    | Visibility | Selectable | Color |   Cond. formatting    | Color |   Cond. formatting   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
41167307 | No  |   No   | Black |   Invalid   | Black |      Yes       |  Visible   |     No     | Grey  |          No           | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
50200912 | No  |   No   | Black |    Valid    | Black |       No       | Invisible  |    N/A     |  N/A  |          No           | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5859221  | No  |   No   | Black |    Valid    | Black |       No       |  Visible   |     No     | Grey  |          No           | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
38120777 | No  |   No   | Black |    Valid    | Black |       No       | Invisible  |    N/A     |  N/A  |          No           | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
54860799 | Yes |   No   | Grey  |   Invalid   | Black |      Yes       | Invisible  |    N/A     |  N/A  |          No           | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
52661024 | Yes |   No   | Grey  |   Invalid   | Black |      Yes       | Invisible  |    N/A     |  N/A  |          No           | Black | select:invalid{Grey} |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8442831  | Yes |   No   | Grey  |   Invalid   | Black |      Yes       | Invisible  |    N/A     |  N/A  |          No           | Black | select:invalid{Grey} |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
29806043 | Yes |   No   | Grey  |   Invalid   | Black |      Yes       | Invisible  |    N/A     |  N/A  |          No           | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
61966461 | Yes |   No   | Grey  |   Invalid   | Black |      Yes       | Invisible  |    N/A     |  N/A  | select:valid{visible} | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
44406771 | Yes |   No   | Grey  |   Invalid   | Grey  |      No        |  Visible   |     No     | Grey  |          No           | Black | select:invalid{Grey} |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
40603035 | Yes |   No   | Black |    Valid    | Black |      No        | Invisible  |    N/A     |  N/A  |          No           | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22994211 | Yes |   No   | Grey  |    Valid    | Black |      No        | Invisible  |    N/A     |  N/A  |          No           | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21722343 | Yes |   No   | Grey  |    Valid    | Grey  |      No        | Invisible  |    N/A     |  N/A  |          No           | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
48960650 | Yes |  Yes   | Grey  |   Invalid   | Black |      No        | Invisible  |    N/A     |  N/A  |          No           | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5805194  | Yes |  Yes   | Grey  |    Valid    | Black |      No        |  Visible   |    Yes     | Black |          No           | Black |          No          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
50840409 | Yes |  Yes   | Grey  |    Valid    | Black |      Yes       |  Visible   |    Yes     | Grey  |          No           | Black |          No          |
```

Answer (score 3):

See this answer :

```
<select>
        <option style="display: none;" value="" selected>SelectType</option>
        <option value="1">Type 1</option>
        <option value="2">Type 2</option>
        <option value="3">Type 3</option>
        <option value="4">Type 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my contribution. Haml + CoffeeScript + [SCSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(stylesheet_language))

#### Haml

```
=f.collection_select :country_id, [us] + Country.all, :id, :name, {prompt: t('user.country')}, class: 'form-control'
```

#### CoffeeScript

```
  $('select').on 'change', ->
    if $(this).val()
      $(this).css('color', 'black')
    else
      $(this).css('color', 'gray')
  $('select').change()
```

#### SCSS

```
select option {
  color: black;
}
```

It's possible to use only CSS by changing the server code and only setting the class styles depending on the current value of the property, but this way seems easier and cleaner.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    return $(this).css('color', 'black');
  } else {
    return $(this).css('color', 'gray');
  }
});

$('select').change();
```

```css
    select option {
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="user[country_id]" id="user_country_id">
  <option value="">Country</option>
                      <option value="231">United States</option>
                      <option value="1">Andorra</option>
                      <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
                      <option value="248">Zimbabwe</option></select>
```

You can add more CSS (`select option:first-child`) to keep the placeholder gray when it opens, but I didn't care about that.

Answer (score 0):

In **Angular** we can add an option as placeholder that **can be hidden** in option dropdown.
We can even add a **custom dropdown icon** as background that **replaces browser dropdown** icon.

The **trick** is to **enable placeholder** css only when **value is not selected**

**/**My Component Template*/**

```
 <div class="dropdown">
      <select [ngClass]="{'placeholder': !myForm.value.myField}"
 class="form-control" formControlName="myField">
        <option value="" hidden >Select a Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

**/**My Component.TS */**

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.fb.build({
    myField: ''
  });
}
```

**/**global.scss*/**

```
.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: no-repeat white;
  background-image:url('angle-arrow-down.svg');
  background-position: center right;
  select {
    background: transparent;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    /*For moz*/
    -moz-appearance: none;
    /* IE10 */
    &::-ms-expand {
      display: none;
    }
    /*For chrome*/
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    &.placeholder {
      opacity: 0.7;
      color: theme-color('mutedColor');
    }
    option {
      color: black;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution for Angular 2

Create a label on top of the select

```
<label class="hidden-label" for="IsActive"
    *ngIf="filterIsActive == undefined">Placeholder text</label>
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="filterIsActive"
    [(ngModel)]="filterIsActive" id="IsActive">
    <option value="true">true</option>
    <option value="false">false</option>
</select>
```

and apply CSS to place it on top

```
.hidden-label {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: .34rem;
    margin-left: .56rem;
    font-style: italic;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

`pointer-events: none` allows you to display the select when you click on the label, which is hidden when you select an option.

[[image]angular](/questions/tagged/angular) [html](/questions/tagged/html) [css](/questions/tagged/css)

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading this and using React, use defaultValue.

```
<option defaultValue>Select a country here</option>
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on [Albireo's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805194/1762224), this version uses no jQuery and the CSS specificity is better.

```js
const triggerEvent = (el, eventName) => {
  let event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents')
  event.initEvent(eventName, true, false)
  el.dispatchEvent(event)
}

let select = document.querySelector('.placeholder-select')
select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  e.target.classList[e.target.value == 0 ? 'add' : 'remove']('empty')
})
triggerEvent(select, 'change')
```

```css
.placeholder-select option {
  color: #000000;
}
.placeholder-select option:first-child {
  color: #444444;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.placeholder-select.empty {
  color: #7F7F7F;
}
```

```html
<select class="placeholder-select">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose...</option>
  <option value="1">Something</option>
  <option value="2">Something else</option>
  <option value="3">Another choice</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Plain JavaScript solution that allows the user to reset the field by only disabling the option when no value is selected.**

I didn't liked the way to just disable the option (even though it is indeed a very simple solution). But I had the requirement to reset the select box. So I created that plain JavaScript solution below.

All you have to do in the HTML code is the following:

```
<select name="animal">
    <option class="placeholder">Animal</option>
    <option value="1">Mouse</option>
    <option value="2">Cat</option>
</select>
```

To get this to work, just include following code in a `script`-block at the end of the HTML body.

```
(function () {
    const selectboxPlaceholderOptions = document.querySelectorAll('select option.placeholder');

    function selectBoxChange(event) {
        const select = event.srcElement;
        const placeholderOption = event.srcElement.querySelector('option.placeholder');
        if (!placeholderOption)
            return;

        if (!select.value || select.value === '') {
            placeholderOption.disabled = true;
            placeholderOption.textContent = placeholderOption.dataset['placeholderText'];
        } else {
            placeholderOption.disabled = false;
            placeholderOption.textContent = '';
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < selectboxPlaceholderOptions.length; i++) {
        const option = selectboxPlaceholderOptions[i];
        const select = option.parentElement;

        option.value = '';
        option.disabled = true;
        option.dataset['placeholderText'] = option.textContent;
        select.addEventListener("change", selectBoxChange);
    }
})();
```

With the class `placeholder` assigned to the placeholder-option, everything is done. The JavaScript works with every select-box that is available until the end of page load.

Answer (score -1):

Ok,one that does the trick in my case, features (opposed to the accepted answer):

- Grey if it's the placeholder
- Selection is NOT required
- Able to change back to greyed (value = "")
- No external libraries (jquery etc)

It takes a small JS function to change it back grey/black if the value isnt "".
The JS is explaned in the comments.. without comments only a few lines of code.
By puting this in a function it will work for all checkboxes with this class..

```js
function checkSelectboxes(){
    // select all checkboxes, here i choose to do so based on classname
    let selectboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.form-select'); 
    // loop through all checkboxes (only one this time)
    selectboxes.forEach(sb=>{   
      //add eventlistener to each checkbox
      sb.addEventListener('change',function(e){
      // if the value of this checkbox isnt "" Then add class, otherwise : remove it.
        e.target.value!=="" ? e.target.classList.add('changed') : e.target.classList.remove('changed');
      })
    })
  }
  
  //call the function
  checkSelectboxes();
```

```css
.form-select{
  color:#ccc;
}
.form-select.changed{
  color:#000
}

.form-select option{
    color:#000;
}
.form-select option:first-of-type{
    color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<!-- give the first option an empty value , and set it as selected-->
<select type="text" class="form-select" >
  <option value="" selected>-- My placeholder --</option>
  <option>1 lorem --</option>
  <option>2 ipsum --</option>
  <option>3 dolor --</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this for a change:

```
$("select").css("color", "#757575");
$(document).on("change", "select", function(){
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $(this).css("color", "");
    } 
    else {
        $(this).css("color", "#757575");
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is [a working example](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=7333a033-6a7c-4880-b577-ff9c56356f15) how to achieve this with pure JavaScript that handles the options color after the first click:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #myselect {
        color: gray;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <select id="myselect">
      <option disabled selected>Choose Item
      </option>

      <option>Item 1
      </option>

      <option>Item 2
      </option>

      <option>Item 3
      </option>
    </select>

    <script>
      // Add event listener to change color in the first click
      document.getElementById("myselect").addEventListener("click", setColor)
      function setColor()
      {
        var combo = document.getElementById("myselect");
        combo.style.color = 'red';
        // Remove Event Listener after the color is changed at the first click
        combo.removeEventListener("click", setColor);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Using the classnames package, here's a solution that worked with my React functional component.  My component uses hooks, but that's probably not important to the solution.  This approach is a functional riff off of the class based solution nicely described here...
https://www.derpturkey.com/select-placeholder-with-react/

COMPONENT JS...

```
function NavBar(props, prevProps) {
            const ClassNames = require("classnames");  // package needs require rather than import
            const [where, changeWhere] = useState("");  // my component's value
            // classnames will add placeholderSelect class if chosen option's value is empty
            let whereClass = ClassNames("myOtherStyleRules", {
                placeholderSelect: !where,
            });
            ...
            return (
            ...
            <div id="where">
                            <select
                              className={whereClass}
                              value={where}
                              ...
                            >
                              <option value="" hidden> where? </option>    //  value must be empty, hidden from choice
                              <option value="24">Anchorage</option>
                              <option value="27">Birmingham</option>
                              <option value="28">Detroit</option>
                              <option value="25">Los Angeles</option>
                              <option value="26">Oahu</option>
                              <option value="29">Seattle</option>
                            </select>
                ...
```

COMPONENT CSS...

```
        .placeholderSelect {
          color: rgb(167, 167, 167);
        }
```

Comment: Although a convenient reference here (for one segment of users), this probably is better suited to a separate post about React and form fields.