# Drop down list that doesnt show the first element?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I create a drop down list that doesn't show when You expand the drop down list? (because the first element has text `"Please make selection"` and no value. Plus, it looks bad with the please select in the list right under the same text.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create an option group ([example here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup)) so that it's not selectable, or just leave the first option blank and add your own validation for the dropdown.  A blank one would just be:

```
<option value="-1"></option>
```

Comment: I was more interested from the server side(ASP.NET)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible immediately from the server-side. You'll have to include a special option, and add some CSS and javascript. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder) for a solution (and check out the JsFiddle he added).