# A Placeholder for the `select` tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering how to achieve the `placeholder` effect with the `select` tag, it would be really nice to have the default selected option something like "Please Chose an Option:".

I have tried some variations and they are not working so far and I'm sure that it can be achieved cause i seen it somewhere (can't remember where).

I have tried this:

1)

```
<fieldset>
            <select data-placeholder="Please select a product" id="s1" class="global">
                <option value="Some">Some</option>
                <option value="Slower">Slower</option>
                <option value="Slow">Slow</option>
                <option value="Fast">Fast</option>
                <option value="Faster">Faster</option>
            </select>
</fieldset>
```

2)

```
<fieldset>
            <select id="s1" class="global">
                <option data-placeholder="true"  value="Some">Some</option>
                <option value="Slower">Slower</option>
                <option value="Slow">Slow</option>
                <option value="Fast">Fast</option>
                <option value="Faster">Faster</option>
            </select>
</fieldset>
```

Both are not working, maybe there is a jQuery method to make that?

**Quick edit:** I DON'T want to just disable one of the options and make it `selected` because it will still be showed in the drop-down list with the other items.

Comment: Already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder
There's also a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmf6t/
(anyway it does not work so good on chrome...)

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations - I don't want to do that this way, there is no just black and white and i may have different ideas from yours which can be achieved (I didn't asked for something impossible, I'm sure it can be done) or at least something close like Luciano and Truth suggested.

Comment: Similar Question with a tested and accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603055/placeholder-for-select-tag

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's two types of placeholder, re-selectable and hidden:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lachlan/FuNmc/

Re-selectable placeholder:

```
<select>
    <option value="" selected>Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Hidden placeholder:

```
<select class="empty">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

CSS to change the colour of the first item:

```
select option { color: black; }
select option:first-child { color: grey; }
select.empty { color: grey; }
/* Hidden placeholder */
select option[disabled]:first-child { display: none; }
```

And a little jQuery to toggle the font-color after selection:

```
// Applies to all select boxes that have no value for their first option
$("select:has(option[value=]:first-child)").on('change', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("empty", $.inArray($(this).val(), ['', null]) >= 0);
}).trigger('change');
```

Inspiration:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805194/1196148 - re-selectable placeholder
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8442831/1196148 - hidden placeholder

Answer (score 4):

I've built a simple demo by following @Truth suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/6QnXF/

```
(function($){
    $('#myAwesomeSelect').change(function(){
       if( !$(this).data('removedPlaceHolder'))
       {
          $(this).find('option:first').remove();
          $(this).data('removedPlaceHolder', true); 
       }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Firefox (10) doesn't show the disabled option as the default selection (placeholder), but shows the next one (Option #1).

Comment: Same in IE 9.  Option #1 is selected by default, and if I expand the dropdown, the default option shows in gray.  I think you need to also add `selected="selected"` to the first item.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no way doing it with HTML alone (though that would be nice.)
You can fake it with a selected option (I know you don't want it, but it's probably the only way). Once another option is selected, you can remove it.

**[Here's a working example of what I describe.](http://jsfiddle.net/5gxjV/)**

Comment: Chrome 22 shows the placeholder text in the same color as the other options, but Firefox 14 shows the placeholder text gray as intended.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're going to have to construct your own workaround for a select box. Something like a series of divs that act as options which when clicked are shown and have their value inserted into a hidden input field.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
add this in css(style sheet):

```
select:required:invalid {
 color: #c4c4c4;
}
option[value=""][disabled] {
 display: none;
}
option {
 color: #232423;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<select required>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select a color</option>
 <option value="red">Red</option>
 <option value="green">Green</option>
```