# placeholder for select tag

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a placeholder on a select tag?

```
<select placeholder="select your beverage">

   <option>Tea</option>

   <option>coffee</option>

   <option>soda</option>

</select>
```

or may be a possible work around?

Comment: It makes no sense to have a placeholder on a select - there's no way to be confused about what values may be selected as they are listed in the element. The only time this could be an issue is if you are trying to use a placeholder as a substitute for a label, which the specification says you should not do.

Comment: @Quentin, What is above specification or design consistency? Please have a look ta Select2 plugin allowing to set a lot of cool stuff along with placeholder. It is a the jQuery replacement for select boxes. Herer is an official site https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: Why not `optgroup`? See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36265421/1320932

Comment: @Quentin He wants to show a value in the select, which isn't actually a selected value, telling the user to make a selection (when one has not yet been made). When you then make a selection (tea, coffee, or soda), the placeholder is replaced with the selected text.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

EDIT: This did/does work at the time I wrote it, but as Blexen pointed out, it's not in the spec.

Add an option like so:

```
<option default>Select Your Beverage</option>
```

The correct way:

```
<option selected="selected">Select Your Beverage</option>
```

Comment: What version of HTML is the `default` attribute from?

Comment: Sorry, but AFAIK this is just plain wrong. "default" isn't a valid attribute in any spec ([HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION) or [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element))

Comment: So you're not wrong - but this did/does work. I will update my answer but the down vote was not really necessary :)

Comment: Also We can use `disabled selected hidden` or Only `hidden`

Comment: Don't forget to add ' value="" ' - that fixes a lot of bugs when working with certain frameworks such as AngularJS

Answer (score 96):

According to [Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select), `placeholder` is not a valid attribute on a `<select>` input.

Instead, add an option with an empty `value` and the `selected` attribute, as shown below. The empty `value` attribute is mandatory to prevent the default behaviour which is to use the contents of the `<option>` as the `<option>`'s value.

```
<select>
    <option value="" selected>select your beverage</option>
    <option value="tea">Tea</option>
    <option value="coffee">Coffee</option>
    <option value="soda">Soda</option>
</select>
```

In modern browsers, adding the `required` attribute to the `<select>` element will not allow the user to submit the form which the element is part of if the selected option has an empty value.

If you want to style the default option inside the list *(which appears when clicking the element)*, there's a limited number of CSS properties that are well-supported. `color` and `background-color` are the 2 safest bets, other CSS properties are likely to be ignored.

In my option the best way (in HTML5) to mark the default option is using the custom `data-*` attributes.<sup>1</sup> Here's how to style the default option to be greyed out:

```css
select option[data-default] {
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="" selected data-default>select your beverage</option>
  <option value="tea">Tea</option>
  <option value="coffee">Coffee</option>
  <option value="soda">Soda</option>
</select>
```

However, this will only style the item inside the drop-down list, not the value displayed on the input. If you want to style that with CSS, target your `<select>` element directly. In that case, you can only change the style of the currently selected element at any time.<sup>2</sup>

If you wanted to make it slightly harder for the user to select the default item, you could set the `display: none;` CSS rule on the `<option>`, but remember that this ***will not*** prevent users from selecting it (using e.g. arrow keys/typing), this just makes it harder for them to do so.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> This answer previously advised the use of a `default` attribute which is non-standard and has no meaning on its own.

<sup>2</sup> It's technically possible to style the select itself based on the selected value using JavaScript, but that's outside the scope of this question. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805194/1344955), however, covers this method.</sub>

Comment: This does nothing in Safari.

Comment: This does nothing in Android :-(

Comment: It should be worth mentioning that this no longer works and that `[default]` is not a real attribute. https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html

Comment: @jnowland I just now saw your comment and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This should be the right answer. In my case, what i wanted to do is to have a default option to show it as a placeholder, but hide it when select box is active; so inside my css style "select option[data-default]" i just set the property "display: none" and voala!

Comment: This is not working in Chrome 70, no effect.

Comment: @AlexanderKim It's working just fine for me, please be more specific on how it's not working.

Comment: @SeinopSys, select's default value is not getting a custom color.

Answer (score 16):

```
<select>

    <option selected="selected" class="Country">Country Name</option>

    <option value="1">India</option>

    <option value="2">us</option>

</select>
```

```
.country
{


    display:none;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Solved my problem

Answer (score 13):

```
     <select>
         <option value="" disabled selected hidden> placeholder</option>
         <option value="op1">op1</option>
         <option value="op2">op2</option>
         <option value="op3">op3</option>
         <option value="op4">op4</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: i really dont know why they gave you negative,but this solved my issue

Answer (score 8):

**Yes it is possible**

> You can do this using only `HTML` You need to set default select
>   option `disabled=""` and `selected=""` and select tag `required=""`.
>   Browser doesn't allow user to submit the form without selecting an
>   option.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name="in-op" required="">
        <option disabled="" selected="">Select Option</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

This my function for select box placeholder.

HTML

```
<select name="country" id="country">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Country</option>
  <option value="c1">England</option>
  <option value="c2">Russia</option>
  <option value="c3">USA</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
     jQuery(function($) {
      /*function for placeholder select*/
      function selectPlaceholder(selectID){
        var selected = $(selectID + ' option:selected');
        var val = selected.val();
        $(selectID + ' option' ).css('color', '#333');
        selected.css('color', '#999');
        if (val == "") {
          $(selectID).css('color', '#999');
        };
        $(selectID).change(function(){
          var val = $(selectID + ' option:selected' ).val();
          if (val == "") {
            $(selectID).css('color', '#999');
          }else{
            $(selectID).css('color', '#333');
          };
        });
      };

      selectPlaceholder('#country');

    });
```

Comment: I liked your answer. But Select2 is better because of allowClear option, no offence. :)

Comment: This is a good solution for flexibility. The unselected option appears as a placeholder of the select element, then as a completed field when selected. Best option in my opinion.

Comment: This could be done using pure JS, without jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

No need to take any javscript or any method you can just do it with your html css

HTML

```
<select id="myAwesomeSelect">
    <option selected="selected" class="s">Country Name</option>
    <option value="1">Option #1</option>
    <option value="2">Option #2</option>

</select>
```

Css

```
.s
{
    color:white;
        font-size:0px;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This does nothing in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Select2 plugin allowing to set a lot of cool stuff along with placeholder. It is a jQuery replacement for select boxes. Here is an official site https://select2.github.io/examples.html

The thing is - if you want to disable fancy search option, please use the following option set.

```
data-plugin-options='
{ 
    "placeholder": "Select status",
    "allowClear": true, 
    "minimumResultsForSearch": -1
}
```

Especially I like the allowClear option.

Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

```
<select>
   <option disabled selected>select your beverage</option>
   <option >Tea</option>
   <option>coffee</option>
   <option>soda</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please don't just dump code as an answer, explain your thoughts so users can better understand what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control"name="country">
<option class="servce_pro_disabled">Select Country</option>
<option class="servce_pro_disabled" value="Aruba" id="cl_country_option">Aruba</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-control option:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```