# How to add placeholder for select2?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, ui-select2, select2-rails

Yeah we can add placeholder to select2 like this,

```
$("#e2_2").select2({
placeholder: "Select a State"
});
```

But I need something like this, [image]

Here you can see linkedin provides "Type another area of expertise". Means when you select expertise again it show placeholder for selection. I want to do same thing using select2.

Please help.

Comment: Hi. Have you try: $("#select2id").attr("placeholder","whatever")

Comment: hey dude. check this, hope it help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17603167/3069595

Comment: before reading the question @JSG33kC0d3 linked to, I was going to suggest adding an option with an empty value, e.g. `<option value=""></option>`. I'm not sure if that will work with the tag option but that's how select2 normally shows the placeholder set in the initialisation when used 'normally'.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's isn't a feature of this plugin. The placeholder is "placed" only in first input field. When you "save" the first element the plugin generate a static html with a new field without any placeholder. I think to change this behavior you need to change the plugin source code.

You can find the "template" of second input inside the file:

*[root]/select2-4.0.0/src/js/select2/dropdown/*`search.js`