# Default option for <select> in MVC 5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using `<select>` like this in an ASP.NET MVC 5 app:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1" class="text-primary">Select Static Analysis Tool</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="ToolName" id="sel1" required>
    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.ToolList)
    {
      <option>@item</option>
    }
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-lg" />
</div>
```

I want to have a default text like `Please Select` in the `<select>` menu. How can I get that?

Comment: Just add `<option>Please select</option>` before the loop. But seriously your using MVC and not using html helpers?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i want to use bootstrap and writing Html Helpers for bootstrap is time consuming for me. Also can not use the `TwiiterBootstrapMVC`

Comment: @StephenMuecke But in the case that you have mentioned user can select `Please Select` and submit that. How can i stop user from doing that?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603055/placeholder-for-select-tag

Comment: <option disabled selected>--Select Item--</option>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify you code and use strongly typed model binding using MVC's html helpers

Assuming you model property is

```
[Display(Name = "Select Static Analysis Tool")]
[Required]
public string ToolName { get; set; }
```

Then in the view

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ToolName, new { @class = "text-primary" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ToolName, new SelectList(ViewBag.ToolList), "-Please select-", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ToolName)
```

which will produce the following html for the select

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="ToolName" name="ToolName">
  <option value>-please select-</option>
  <option>Tool Name 1</option>
  <option>Tool Name 2</option>
  ....
</select>
```

Note the first option has a `null` value so validation will fail if the first option is selected.

And if you want to reduce those 3 lines even further, your can consider the options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162218/editortemplate-for-dropdownlist/26417466#26417466)

Answer (score 1):

Echoing Skelly's link in the comments (and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603055/placeholder-for-select-tag#comment42707505_17603055) too), I'd caution you that this just isn't how `<select>` lists are designed to work.  A label will serve the same purpose, and is designed for this.  If you do move ahead in this way, you're forced to start asking questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169738/default-text-with-bootstrap-in-select#comment44709967_28169738):

> "user can select Please Select and submit that. How can i stop user
>   from doing that?"

And now things are looking a little bit more hacky.

In any case, I think this is the wrong way to go about things, but here's how I would do it.  First, I'd use a ViewModel (not ViewBag) and incorporate the `<select>` list into it.  This way, you can use HTML helpers: which I believe is the more orthodox way to create a `SelectList` in MVC5.

```
public class ToolViewModel {
    public ToolDropdownList ToolDropdownList { get; set; }
    public string SelectedTool { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class ToolDropdownList {
    public List<SelectListItem> Tools { get; set; }
}
```

Prior to the View being rendered using the `ToolViewModel` ViewModel, `ToolDropdownList` would have to be populated with `SelectListItem`s.  Each of these would represent a tool on the select list, with a `Text`, `Value`, and `Selected` attribute.

This is where you would add the `Please select` SelectListItem.

Then I'd render the view using HTML helpers and decorate the helpers with your Bootstrap classes.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedTool, new { @class="text-primary" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTool,
        new SelectList(Model.ToolDropdownList.Tools, "Value", "Text"),
        new { @class = "form-control", @id = "sel1", @required = "required" })
</div>
```

If you still *reeeeally* wanted to allow a user to submit a form with `Please select...` selected, you could opt for some sort of special client or server-side validation rules to allow this.