# ReactJS select Option placeholder not getting picked up

Tags: reactjs

I am populating the select-options using a value map, by looping through the value map and add them to the options. However, as the placeholder I want some default text to appear. But its not being picked up.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class DropdownComponent extends React.Component {

handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>

                {
                    this.props.valueMap.map((i) => {
                        return <option key={i.code} placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                                       value={i.code}>{i.code}</option>

                    })}
            </select>
        )
    }
}
DropdownComponent.defaultProps = {
    name: 'womensObstetrics.referralReason',
    htmlFieldtype: 'select',
    placeholder: 'Reason for referral',
    label: 'Reason for referral',
    valueMap: [
        {
            code: "Some code",
            label: "Please Select"
        },
        {
            code: "Maternity",
            label: "Maternity"
        },
        {
            code: "Other",
            label: "Other"
        }
    ]
}
export default DropdownComponent;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y7aW.jpg)

Comment: `<option>` tag doesn't have a placeholder attribute. you should use `selected` prop instead. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17603167/2315280)

Comment: But since I am generating option tags dynamically, I don't know what is the general way of populating the default option and then add the remaining actual tags.

Comment: Add an extra option before the `map` with the default value of your choice.