# I want to use require for <select> except one disabled option selected by default

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want stop the form submission if the default disabled option is selected.

i tried `required` attribute on all of the child elements.

here is my Code:

```
<div class="form-group form-check">
    <label>who you are?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="usertype" required>
       <option disabled selected>Select user Type</option>
       <option value="user">user</option>
       <option value="admin">admin</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want to submit the form if the user select one of the two option not third one.

is there any HTML trick/Attribute to tackle this problem, or some Jquery please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [placeholder for select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603055/placeholder-for-select-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `value=""` on the default option. When you use `required` there must be a value selected for the control to be valid

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <label>who you are?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="usertype" required>
      <option value=""> Select user Type</option>
      <option value="user">user</option>
      <option value="admin">admin</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```