# Default Writing, On a Bootstrap selection bar HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In my default selection it shows the first element in the list "Select a genre". That is how I want to see it but I dont want it ("select a genre") to be select able and seen in the list

```
        <div class="wrapper">   

                <select id="first-disabled" class="selectpicker" data-hide-disabled="true" data-live-search="true">
                <optgroup  >
                <option>Select a Genre</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Rock">
                  <option>Punk Rock</option>
                  <option>Hard Rock</option>

                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Pop">
                  <option>Turkish Pop</option>
                  <option>English Pop</option>
                </optgroup>

              </select>

        </div>
```

---

```
  .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 326px;
  left: -42px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
}
```

As it can be seen in the code my first option seems to be the default selection.  As you can see my div wrapper css behind my selection bar code. I use custom bootstrap bar. As it can be seen in the image it can be seen and selectable in the option list.

here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it non-selectable by adding the property `disabled` to it.

```
<option value="" disabled="disabled">Select a Genre</option>
```

In regards to hiding it from the list, I don't believe you can do this natively. You might be able to using javascript, but not with strict HTML. If it were me, I would stick with the native HTML semantics of showing it in the list.

This other question on SO might help: [A Placeholder for the `select` tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368847/a-placeholder-for-the-select-tag)

UPDATE:

You could hide it using inline-styling maybe?

```
<option value="" disabled="disabled" style="display:none;">Select a Genre</option>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/11dpc8m7/

Comment: I checked that question and tried the demo, it is similiar but not same I guess, the problem still remains. I guess it cannot be done by making "Select a Genre" option dissapear from the list with html only

Comment: No, because the options in a list are meant to be shown there by default. But you can at least make the initial one disabled, so it cannot be selected once the menu is open.

Comment: You could add inline-styling to it to make it display none?

Comment: look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/w1o2f7yy/ - here it works

Comment: Yeah, I've just updated my answer with a similar approach. Well, the same method, different approach. It seems to work though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<div class="wrapper">   
    <select id="first-disabled" class="selectpicker" data-hide-disabled="true" data-live-search="true">
        <optgroup class="hidden">
            <option disabled selected>Select a Genre</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Rock">
            <option>Punk Rock</option>
            <option>Hard Rock</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Pop">
            <option>Turkish Pop</option>
            <option>English Pop</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

And with this additional CSS

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

A fiddle of this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/w1o2f7yy/

Comment: It writes "Nothing selected" instead of "Select a Genre"

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one sir:

```
<label>Type of Business</label>
<select class="form-control">
   <optgroup  >
                <option>Select a Genre</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Rock">
                     <option disabled>──────────</option>
                  <option>Punk Rock</option>
                  <option>Hard Rock</option>

                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Pop">
                    <option disabled>──────────</option>
                  <option>Turkish Pop</option>
                  <option>English Pop</option>
                </optgroup>
</select>
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/tYGs5/114/)