# How to make "Select" text invisible in drop down (created by <select> <option> tags)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `<select>` `<option>` to create my drop down. I've 5 options where one is `Select Status` & remeining are the actual options. What I want is, when user uses drop down
1. `Select status` should be greyed out and read only. 
2. User should only be able to see & choose remining option only.

For example, drop down is as following:

Select Status - This should be greyed out & read only.

All Menus

Enabled

Disabled

Demo

I can make `Select Status` greyed out but after that I'm unable to achieve my task.

HTML Code:

```
<div>
  <select id="menuStatusFilter" style="padding: 4px 8px; width: 100%;">
    <option style="color:gray" value="null" >Select Status</option>
    <option>All Menus</option>
    <option>Enabled</option>
    <option>Disabled</option>
    <option>Demo</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#menuStatusFilter').color('gray');
  $('#menuStatusFilter').click(function () {
    var current = $('#select').val();
    if (current == 'null') {
      $('#menuStatusFilter').color('black');
    } else {
      $('#menuStatusFilter').color('gray');
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dhrkja7c/

I am new to `JavaScript` so my query may looks very simple.exploring.

Comment: A similar question with the same purposes was already answered. [Take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368847/a-placeholder-for-the-select-tag)

Comment: @tpsilva Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

here's one option

https://jsfiddle.net/dhrkja7c/1/

```
  var current = "null"; var last = 'null';
  $('#menuStatusFilter').change(function () {
    last = current;
    current = $(this).val();
    if (current === 'null') {
      $('#menuStatusFilter').val(last);
      alert("cant change it back youre stuck");
    }
  });
```