# Show "Placeholder" in HTML Select when no option is chosen

Tags: html, jquery

I add a "Placeholder" to a an existing select. When I select any option and then pick the blank item , the placeholder is not shown anymore. How to always show it whenever no option is selected?

```
var l = $("#my_select");
if (l.val() === '') {
    l.append($('<option>', { value: 1, text: 'Some Placeholder', disabled : true, selected: true, hidden: true }))
}
```

Comment: What blank item?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A Placeholder for the \`select\` tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368847/a-placeholder-for-the-select-tag)

Comment: @smolo i answered your question since it seems to be no duplicate - please give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You merged `disabled` and `hidden` together. Therefor the placeholder is in the list of options not selectable and not visible. If you just want it to be visible omit `hidden`. If you also want to reselect the placeholder omit both.

```html
<select id="selected">
  <option value="" selected>placeholder</option>
  <option value="1">troet</option>
  <option value="2">quak</option>
</select>
<label for="selected">selected</label>
<br>
<select id="disabled">
  <option value="" selected disabled>placeholder</option>
  <option value="1">troet</option>
  <option value="2">quak</option>
</select>
<label for="disabled">disabled</label>
<br>
<select id="hidden">
  <option value="" selected hidden>placeholder</option>
  <option value="1">troet</option>
  <option value="2">quak</option>
</select>
<label for="hidden">hidden</label>
```