# Removing a "default" <option> in a select box

Tags: html, html-select

Here is my select box:

```
<select id="category">
   <option value="">Pick a choice!</option>
   <option value="">choice1</option>
   <option value="">choice2</option>
   <option value="">choice3</option>
   <option value="">choice4</option>
</select>
```

I want the  `Pick a choice!` option to be removed when the user click on the select box. If the user click anywhere else, the `Pick a choice!` option come back. I don't want the user to be able to pick the `Pick a choice!` option. What should I do?

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript. You may wish to consider using a JS library, such as [tag:jquery], [tag:mootools], [tag:scriptaculous]...

Comment: You need to write some Javascript to achieve this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder ??

Comment: I'll try to do something with JQuery

Comment: Why not just use the HTML<optgroup> tag? It would say "Pick a choice!" but it can't be selected. No JavaScript needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without some PHP or JavaScript to remove the option dynamically you do have another very simple option that I use regularly, this is the `disabled="disabled"` option. The option will remain but the user won't be able to actually select it.

The failure with this is if someone just submits a form without choosing anything the empty value will submit in the form, but this is where your validation handling comes into play.

Your code for the "Pick a choice!" option will look something like this:

`<option disabled="disabled">Pick a choice!</option>`

I hope it helps.

Comment: i found this answer earlier, but it isn't enought. "pick a choice!" need to be completely removed i'm trying something in JQuery to put it in display: none; posting answer soon. Thx for your help !

Comment: I appreciate the feedback Charles, just a tip for the future, if you're looking for options it is best to list the languages you're working with, preferably listing them in the tags but even written in the question is OK. The reason being is I have a number of solutions with PHP that I can write without thinking, there are others like that with JS and jQuery. Notice how nobody has given you an answer using jQuery - just a comment with the suggestion to try it, it's greatly because you didn't tag it as being acceptable in your answer, plus there is no previous tries shown with jQuery. Good luck

Answer (score 7):

## CSS Only Sol'n

---

So, I know this post is quite old now, but a css only solution wasn't offered... Much more efficient way of accomplishing this. Notice the first **`<option>`** doesn't have a value attribute; this allows it to effectively placehold.

```css
#category:focus option:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="category">
   <option>Pick a choice!</option>
   <option value="choice1">choice1</option>
   <option value="choice2">choice2</option>
   <option value="choice3">choice3</option>
   <option value="choice3">choice4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some workaround. Don't know wether this is suite your requirement.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function doremove()
{

    var obj=document.getElementById("category");
    obj.remove(0);  
}

function addOpt()
{
var obj=document.getElementById("category");
var option=document.createElement("option");
option.text="Pick a choice!";
option.value = 0;
obj.add(option,1);
obj.value = 0;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="category" onfocus="doremove();" onblur="addOpt();">
   <option value="0">Pick a choice!</option>
   <option value="">choice1</option>
   <option value="">choice2</option>
   <option value="">choice3</option>
   <option value="">choice4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#SelectID option:first").remove();
```

Comment: This code is works well as per the OP's question. Do not see any point in the negative vote.

Comment: There is a distinct lack of context for how and why this solution is appropriate and applicable. Additionally, it uses jquery, which OP makes no reference to.