# How do I need to add 'Please select...' option for the dropdown list box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code I have to add 'please select..' in the dropdown list box.

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("defaultSelection", new SelectList(Model.VariableDefaultSelections.ToList(), "ba_Object_id", "ba_Object_id", ViewData["DefaultSelectId"]))%>
```

Can any body help me out .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [overload of the DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492883.aspx) helper which allows you to achieve that:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    "defaultSelection", 
    new SelectList(
        Model.VariableDefaultSelections.ToList(), 
        "ba_Object_id", 
        "ba_Object_id", 
        ViewData["DefaultSelectId"]
    ),
    "-- Please Select --"
) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add it in your SelectList, maybe with an Id of -1? The only way I know of is to add it as an option. If you are using HTML5, then I think you might be able to add a meta tag, but that might just be for input types. I will double check...

**UPDATE**
It looks like there is nothing like `placeholder` (HTML5 input option) for select. However, it looks like the best you have has already been answered here: [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder)

Answer (score 1):

You could always add the option in list with the disabled option so the user cannot select it once the drop down is clicked.