# setPlaceholder for select element

Tags: php, jquery, css, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a ZendX_Jquery_Form where I am having a trouble setting placeHolder for a select Element.

```
$month->setAttribs(
        array(
            'required'  =>  TRUE,
            'placeHolder'   =>  'Month'
        ));
```

I wanted it too look like this:
[image]

but all I am getting is thi: [image]

On my firebug output html looks like this

```
<select id="months_at_residence-lengthMonth" placeholder="Month" required="1" name="months_at_residence[lengthMonth]">
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is not working.

I need help to set this such that when i click on it placeholder text hides.
Just incase this dont work straight using zend I know this can be done using js/css . If I do it with css and javascript how can I achieve this for all select elements ?

Hope the question was clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Placeholders](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder) don't work with `select` form element, what you should do instead is to use a default value and disable it as follows:

```
$month->addMultiOption('--', 'Month');
$month->setOptions(array('disable' => array('--')));
```

This will output:

```
<select id="country" name="country" class="valid">
    <option disabled="disabled" label="--" value="--">Month</option>
    <option label="January" value="Jan">January</option>
    <option label="February" value="Feb">February</option>
    // ...
</select>
```

Note from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp):

> The placeholder attribute works with the following input types:
>   text, search, url, tel, email, and password.

Comment: this is correct, placeholders don't work with select element.

Comment: I never realized that, well it does work when youre using zend dojo form how is that ? I have been working with dojo and it always has worked

Comment: @Rohan: From the [Dojo Toolkit documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/selects_using_stores/): `We add placeHolder text for FilteringSelect and ComboBox — Select does not support this.`

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the first option in the select the 'placeholder' text?

```
<select id="choice">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose...</option>
    ...
</select>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805194/435460

Comment: I am currently/already doing it like that, Just trying to figure out why setPlaceHolder is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can add the placeholder by jquery:

```
  $("#months_at_residence-lengthMonth").attr("placeholder", "Month");
```

suggested solution here, can be helpful:
http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html