# placeholder in django forms using python

Tags: django, html, internet-explorer

i am using django python, i apply placeholder for my forms fields in forms.py ,like

```
self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class']            = 'form-text'
self.fields['country'].widget.attrs['class']          = 'form-dropdownfield'
self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder']            = 'Email*'
in .css file
.form-text
{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius:8px;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    border:1px solid #D2D2D2;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Question 1:
Place holder working properly in all browser but not in IE,what can i do for IE problem?
Question 2:
Country field is dropdown list,how can apply placeholder for this one?

Comment: This is barely Django/Python-related. You are asking a question about HTML5 in IE.

Answer (score 3):

Placeholders work for INPUT form elements, but not for SELECT (dropdown) elements.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder)  has a number of answers that offer strategies for default values of dropdown elements.

Though I'm not sure, it's possible that many versions of IE don't support the placeholder attribute (and [this post](http://www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=142) suggests that they're unsupported).
If placeholder is unsupported in a version of IE that you want to support, you could try a polyfill such as https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill

Answer (score -1):

No need to take any javscript or any method you can just do it with your html css

HTML

```
<select id="myAwesomeSelect">
    <option selected="selected" class="s">Country Name</option>
    <option value="1">Option #1</option>
    <option value="2">Option #2</option>

</select>
```

Css

```
.s
{
    color:white;
        font-size:0px;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This won't work since OP is using Django, which generates the HTML for `<select>` tags automatically.