# How to set the value attribute for select options?

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

Source JSON data is:

```
[
  {"name":"Alabama","code":"AL"},
  {"name":"Alaska","code":"AK"},
  {"name":"American Samoa","code":"AS"},
  ...
]
```

I try

```
ng-options="i.code as i.name for i in regions"
```

but am getting:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="0">Alabama</option>
<option value="1">Alaska</option>
<option value="2">American Samoa</option>
```

while I am expecting to get:

```
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
```

So, how to get value attributes and get rid of "?" item?

By the way, if I set the $scope.regions to a static JSON instead of AJAX request's result, the empty item disappears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does angularjs include an empty option in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Comment: Use - `region in regions track by region.code` to set the value attribute to the region.code value ;)

Answer (score 75):

What you first tried should work, but the HTML is not what we would expect.  I added an option to handle the initial "no item selected" case:

```
<select ng-options="region.code as region.name for region in regions" ng-model="region">
   <option style="display:none" value="">select a region</option>
</select>
<br>selected: {{region}}
```

The above generates this HTML:

```
<select ng-options="..." ng-model="region" class="...">
   <option style="display:none" value class>select a region</option>
   <option value="0">Alabama</option>
   <option value="1">Alaska</option>
   <option value="2">American Samoa</option>
</select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/vd73G/)

Even though Angular uses numeric integers for the value, the model (i.e., $scope.region) will be set to AL, AK, or AS, as desired.  (The numeric value is used by Angular to lookup the correct array entry when an option is selected from the list.)

This may be confusing when first learning how Angular implements its "select" directive.

Comment: I find it confusion, and a lack of transparency, that the HTML doesn't reflect the value set in the scope...

Comment: It's a different way of thinking.  You are actually selecting a `region` **object**, not a `region.code` **string**.  Once the user has selected something, the `region` **object** will be selected.  Then when you want the code later on, just access `region.code`.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Can someone explain what exactly the syntax "region.code as region.name" is actually "saying"... it just seems to make little sense to me. That "as" keyword just throws me completely, because I think it has no grammatical use in inferring any kind of meaning whatsoever.

Comment: @ProxyTech, I think of it this way: use region.code for the values to assign to the model, but show region.name to the user.  The [API docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select) refer to the region.name part as the `label`.

Comment: @MarkRajcok It's my C# paradigm coming through to cause confusion with the "as" keyword being used for casting from type to another. Then there's my "English language" paradigm, where the keyword "as" means that "region.came" is interacting/superseding "region.code"... completely not the case in the context. Simply very poor syntax in my opinion.

Comment: How would you for this solution implement condition if only one preselect it?

Comment: For me this should have been marked as an answer. Alas I cannot do it.

Comment: This worked for me. But one confusing thing in the example is that the "region" used in the ng-options tag is not the same as the "region" used in the ng-model tag. Probably should have used two different words to make it more clear.

Answer (score 26):

You can't really do this unless you build them yourself in an ng-repeat.

```
<select ng-model="foo">
   <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.code}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

BUT... it's probably not worth it. It's better to leave it function as designed and let Angular handle the inner workings. Angular uses the index this way so you can actually use an entire object as a value. So you can use a drop down binding to select a whole value rather than just a string, which is pretty awesome:

```
<select ng-model="foo" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"></select>

{{foo | json}}
```

Comment: although your first example produces a working/correct select list, and you cautioned against using it, note that it doesn't work well with the rest of Angular.  E.g., this won't work as expected:  <a ng-click="foo = 'AK'">select AK</a>.  In general, the value attribute probably shouldn't be used with the Angular select directive.

Comment: This is a fantastic way around a long running bug regarding `track by` and `select` not working together.  See here for the bug report:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564

Answer (score 22):

If you use the `track by` option, the `value` attribute is correctly written, e.g.:

```
<div ng-init="a = [{label: 'one', value: 15}, {label: 'two', value: 20}]">
    <select ng-model="foo" ng-options="x for x in a track by x.value"/>
</div>
```

produces:

```
<select>
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="15">one</option>
    <option value="20">two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works perfect in Angular 1.3 kittyminky, check your syntax maybe. - This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 7):

If the model specified for the drop down does not exist then angular will generate an empty options element. So you will have to explicitly specify the model on the select like this:

```
<select ng-model="regions[index]" ng-options="....">
```

Refer to the following as it has been answered before:

[Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select) and this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JWb2/5/)

**Update:** Try this instead:

```
<select ng-model="regions[index].code" ng-options="i.code as i.name for i in regions">
</select>

or

<select ng-model="regions[2]" ng-options="r.name for r in regions">
</select>
```

Note that there is no empty options element in the select.

Answer (score 5):

You could modify you model to look like this:

```
$scope.options = {
    "AL" : "Alabama",
    "AK" : "Alaska",
    "AS" : "American Samoa"
  };
```

Then use

```
<select ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in options"></select>
```

Comment: This variant does not work. It produces either options with the same numeric value and text or options with a numeric value and empty text dependent on order: "k as v" or "v as k"

Answer (score 4):

It appears it's not possible to actually use the "value" of a select in any meaningful way as a normal HTML form element and also hook it up to Angular in the approved way with ng-options.  As a compromise, I ended up having to put a hidden input alongside my select and have it track the same model as my select, like this (all very much simplified from real production code for brevity):

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="profile" ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in profiles" name="something_i_dont_care_about">
</select>
<input name="profile_id" type="text" style="margin-left:-10000px;" ng-model="profile"/>
```

Javascript:

```
App.controller('ConnectCtrl',function ConnectCtrl($scope) {
$scope.profiles = [{id:'xyz', name:'a profile'},{id:'abc', name:'another profile'}];
$scope.profile = -1;
}
```

Then, in my server-side code I just looked for `params[:profile_id]` (this happened to be a Rails app, but the same principle applies anywhere).  Because the hidden input tracks the same model as the select, they stay in sync automagically (no additional javascript necessary).  This is the cool part of Angular.  It almost makes up for what it does to the value attribute as a side effect.

Interestingly, I found this technique only worked with input tags that were not hidden (which is why I had to use the margin-left:-10000px; trick to move the input off the page).  These two variations did not work:

```
<input name="profile_id" type="text" style="display:none;" ng-model="profile"/>
```

and

```
<input name="profile_id" type="hidden" ng-model="profile"/>
```

I feel like that must mean I'm missing something.  It seems too weird for it to be a problem with Angular.

Comment: You can use `<input name="profile_id" type="hidden" value="{{profile}}"/>` also.  It works.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
state.name for state in states track by state.code
```

Where states in the JSON array, state is the variable name for each object in the array.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

Try it as below:

```
var scope = $(this).scope();
alert(JSON.stringify(scope.model.options[$('#selOptions').val()].value));
```