# How to set option value using ng:Options

Tags: angularjs

Apparently AngularJS cannot properly construct a list of `<option>` elements as a simple template in IE, so it provides the `ng:Options` directive (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/235).

After looking at the source, I was able to construct the options with the desired labels, as follows ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TVMmz/7/)):

```
<!-- what I'd like to do -->
<select>
    <option ng:repeat='key in keys' value='{{key}}'> {{lookup[key].firstName}} {{lookup[key].lastName}} </option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<!-- what Angular lets me do -->
<select ng-model='key' ng:options='k as lookup[k].firstName + " " + lookup[k].lastName for k in keys'></select>
```

However, when I inspect the options with Firebug, I see that the value is a numeric index, not my desired key value (I was hoping the initial `k` would be used as the option value).

I haven't looked deeply into the code, so don't know if there's another part of the expression that I'm missing (the regex doesn't seem to have any additional relevant keywords).

I was hoping that someone here might know this directive well enough to tell me (1) how to do it, or (2) that I'm out of luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - value attribute for select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803665/angularjs-value-attribute-for-select)

Comment: This answer is what finally made me get it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13808743/199712

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired key value is in the property you specify by ng-model, i.e., `key`.  Add `{{key}}` to the bottom of your HTML (just after your last select list) to see it.

As you discovered, Angular stores the array index in the HTML.  For more about this, see [AngularJS - value attribute for select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803665/angularjs-value-attribute-for-select)

Comment: That makes sense. In the Angular world, the only thing that matters is changes to the model. Unfortunately, I'm trying to blend Angular into some existing JQuery-driven actions. I suppose I could pull `key` out of the scope in my JQuery code, but it's probably easier to just build the selects there as well (I don't get the benefit of interpolation with `ngOptions`, so it's a tossup).