# How to initialize a select value when option is in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

At first I tried `<select name='size' ng-model='sid' ng-options='y.id as y.title for y in arr'>`. But when the form was submitted, the posted variable `size` is not the id `472 473 474` but the index `0 1 2`.

Then I tried `ng-options='y.title for y in arr track by y.id'`. But the selected model `sid` is not `473` but `{"id":473,"title":"bb"}` so I can't make that 473 item as default by `ng-init='sid = 473'`.

At last, I have to use `option ng-repeat='y in arr'` as below. But it seems that ng-init is useless, because it will initialize before the options repeat. How can I make it work?

Thanks.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model='sid' ng-init='sid = 473'>
        <option ng-repeat='y in arr' value='{{ y.id }}'>
            {{ y.id+' - '+y.title }}
        </option>
    </select>
    {{ sid }}
    <button ng-click='sid=474'>change to 474</button>
</div>
<script>
var app =angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope){
    $scope.arr = [{"id":472,"title":"aa"},{"id":473,"title":"bb"},{"id":474,"title":"cc"}];
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hcLVE/86/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to read the docs:

"Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not designed to work together." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

http://jsfiddle.net/qm7f2kqj/

All you needed was to fix up your ng-options:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-init="sid = 473" ng-model='sid'
      ng-options="y.id as ( y.id + ' - ' + y.title) for y in arr">
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="{{sid}}"/>
    {{ sid }}
    <button ng-click='sid=474'>change to 474</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not solve the question. This is what I tried at first! I know `select as` and `track by` cant be used in the same expression.

Comment: Have you tried the fiddle? It seems to work for me, or else I have misunderstood the question. What's missing?

Comment: In this way, when the form was submitted, the posted variable size is not the id 472 473 474 but the index 0 1 2.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing it in a non-angular way. Ideally you'd be making a POST/GET from an angular service using the ng-model value, but since you're not I've updated my answer, and the jsFiddle with an alternative solution.

Comment: Great. It is a good answer, better than my answer which uses a new input with the same ng-model. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18502634/3657140

Using a invisible input  `<input name="profile_id" type="text" style="margin-left:-10000px;" ng-model="profile"/>`

I found a solution but its not ideal. Welcome anyone who has a good idea to share.