# ng-options with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of Objects, eg:

> [Object { id="121",  name="Planes"}, Object { id="212",  name="Buses"}, Object { id="210",  name="Cars"}, .... ]

I want this to appear in a select such as:

```
<select....>
<option value="121"...>Planes</option>
<option value="212"...>Buses</option>
<option value="210"...>Cars</option>
</select>
```

But if I use the following code:

```
 <select.... ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories" .....
```

I get the following (the values are wrong):

```
<select....>
<option value="1"...>Planes</option>
<option value="2"...>Buses</option>
<option value="3"...>Cars</option>
</select>
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Angular uses numeric values for options values in selects, but you can follow up on your select value using ng-model.

You can try (depending on the Angular version) using `track by` to get the correct value into select. `track by category.id` in your case probably.

Check [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803665/angularjs-value-attribute-for-select) also.

EDIT: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-the-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options) question is pretty much the same also. Someone posted a fiddle for you below, so I won't do it now..

Answer (score 1):

Use the track by option within the ng-options directive

```
<select ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories track by category.id" ng-model="category"></select>
```

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0euswm00/2/) for you

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Instead of having "category.id as category.name..." just changed it to "category as category.name..." and it worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Values in the rendered `<select>` might be incorrect, but that does not matter, because the ng-model value will be the id of selected category.

see: https://jsfiddle.net/prappjt3/2/

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful and has helped my understanding.  I can see the access to the correct ID I have with angularjs with your fiddle. One issue I have with this implementation though (and I am sure there is a solution) is if this select is part of a regular html form then the incorrect id gets submitted.

Comment: That's right. But why would you use 'regular form submitting' when working with angular? Are you aware of 'angular form submitting' using ng-model and ng-submit? That's the standard way to achieve this feature.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/jergush/m1xkezk1/