# How to make a preselection for a select list generated by AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select ng-model="team.captain" ng-options="player.name for player in team.players"></select>
```

This correctly creates a select list to choose the team captain. However, by default a blank option is selected. How can we preselect the first player from the list instead?

```
<select ng-model="team.captain" ng-options="player.name for player in team.players" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <option value="0">John</option>
  <option value="1">Bobby</option>
</select>
```

I tried adding `ng-init="team.captain='0'"` but that didn't help.

**Update** Apparently this happens because

> a value referenced by ng-model doesn't exist in a set of options passed to ng-options.

Source: [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select?rq=1)

However, the question still remains why using ng-init doesn't work?

```
<select ng-init="team.captain='0'" ng-model="team.captain" ng-options="player.name for player in team.players"></select>
```

Comment: You can solve with this Magic Trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38700685/3323601

Answer (score 34):

Here's what worked:

```
<select ng-init="team.captain=team.players[0]" 
        ng-model="team.captain" 
        ng-options="player.name for player in team.players"></select>
```

And what didn't work:

```
ng-init="team.captain='0'"
ng-init="team.captain='John'"
```

My guess is that Angular goes beyond simple comparison of values or labels. It probably compares object references.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my answer that the "label" value needs to be reference to the same object in the array.  In other words, this won't work either:  ng-init="{name: 'John'}"

Comment: In case anyone here is trying to achieve the same thing with angular material md-select then check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38639823/3836923

Answer (score 15):

Here's an alternate method for initializing a drop down menu using AngularJS.

(working example on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/galeroy/100ho18L/1/)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="" ng-controller="myController">

    <select 
        ng-model="carSelection"
        ng-options = "x.make for x in cars">
    </select>

    <script>

        function myController($scope) {

            $scope.cars = [
                {"make": "Nissan", "model": "Sentra"},
                {"make": "Honda", "model": "Prelude"},
                {"make": "Toyota", "model": "Prius"}
            ]

            $scope.carSelection = $scope.cars[1]; // this line initializes the drop down menu
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: hey you seem like familiar with initializing combo boxes , just question if it doesn't bother you  , this one if you have one select box ope.carSelection = $scope.cars[1]; what if i want to initialize in a dynamic number of combo boxes and i want to initilize them all the same value what would i do here's my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351051/ng-option-intial-value-select and thank you

Comment: key that it had to be a reference to the same object, I tried using a different object with a corresponding id. +1

Answer (score 5):

As @camus already mentioned in a comment, you need to set the model to a valid "label" value (or reference), not an index value.  This is a bit odd since you can see an index value being used in the HTML.

Angular sets the value attributes in the HTML as follows:

- when using array as datasource, it will be the index of array element in each iteration;
- when using object as datasource, it will be the property name in each iteration.

When an item is selected, Angular looks up the correct entry in the array/object based on the index or property name.

Answer (score 4):

What about [ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected), as seen in   [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61r6x5tL/4/):

```
<select ng-model="val">
  <option ng-repeat="opt in options" ng-selected="$first">
    {{ opt }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: It worked but when used on `option` tag instead of `select`

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this using **ng-model** and **ng-options**.Basically your model and ng-options should be in sync.

When my model (projIndustry in this case) was initialized to some number then I had to use **ind.ID** in ng-options.(ID comparison).
When my model was initialized to object ,then I had to use **ind**(object) in ng-options.(Object comparison)

```
<select data-ng-options="ind.ID as ind.Display_Text for ind in arrIndustries" 
 data-ng-model="projIndustry" ng-change="onIndChange()" />
```

Comment: nice approach !!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using angular 2+, here is what worked.
`

```
<mat-select matNativeControl placeholder="Select Item" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" name="selectedCaseStudyName" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChangeHandler($event)" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':'silver'}">

        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of myItemList" [value]="item.ItemName">
            {{item.ItemName}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>`
```

In .ts,

```
'selectedItem = myItemList[2].ItemName'
```

myItemList is list of objects with one of the fields being ItemName.
Important point is to bind [(ngModel)] to variable selectedItem and then initialize it with the required index of the list.
Whenever you bind `[(ngModule)]`, make sure that you import `NgModule`

```
import {ngModule} from '@angular/core';
```