# Angularjs default value for bound select

Tags: combobox, angularjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a preselection for a select list generated by AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297560/how-to-make-a-preselection-for-a-select-list-generated-by-angularjs)

In the angular tutorial they set a sortOrder scope variable that defaults the sort by select to 'Newest'.

In my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vbahole22/WXLte/1/) I am doing similar but my select value is not selected. Instead i get the blank entry as if i did not set any value in the scope. Yet I can see my sort order and i am emitting the value of the select and it is preset.

```
    //set a default this way also, but not updating the dropdown
$scope.ddlFilter = {
    name: "All Open Events",//doesn't matter what this is, only cares about value
    value: "ALL"//"OPEN"
};
```

I know i can use ng-init to set defaults but i want to be able to do it this way as well.
Any suggestions?

Comment: See the link above -- your answer is `$scope.ddlFilter = $scope.eventFilters[2];` -- the ng-model must reference an element from the same array used in ng-options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using an object instead of an array of objects. It will allow you to reference what you want by a string vs. an array position such as `scope.eventFilters[0]`.

```js
$scope.eventFilters = {
    "OPEN": "All Open Events",
    "UNMAPPED": "All Un-Mapped Events",
    "MAPPED": "All Mapped Events",
    "CLOSED": "All Closed Events (past 8 hours)",
    "ALL": "All Events",
    "OTHER": "Other OpCenter Open Events"
};
```

And then define the default value as a string (key for the object above):

```js
$scope.ddlFilter = "MAPPED";
```

And then on the page change your select to

```html
<select ng-model="ddlFilter" ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in eventFilters"></select>
```

and your filter no longer needs a `.value`, so it will become:

```html
<tr ng:repeat="event in events  | myEventFilter:ddlFilter | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending">
```

See your modified code working here: http://jsfiddle.net/WXLte/2/

Comment: very nice. thank you much.

Comment: I have run into a slight issue with this one unfortunately. The dropdown that i want to fill not only contains those values i have listed here (which you helped me get into an object instead of an array) but there is also a dynamic set of options i need to glom onto this set to be loaded in the dropdown. Those extra values come from an $http call and they come in as name/value pairs. How can i blend those new values with this existing set?

Comment: Make a new question that is more specific to this new issue - This one has been closed. There are a lot of people who can help you if you make it a new question (you can link back to this question if you'd like)

Comment: And, I think what you're looking for is http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.extend (It will extend the current object with new properties). It works a lot like [jQuerys](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) version.