# Angular, using select input filter to update route?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have my app set up where a list of products can be filtered by colour using a select input, I also have the `$routeprovider` passing this colour param to the page if it is present in the url.

What I want to do now is update the url / route when the select box is changed. How do I bind the change of the select to the route?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

select has an [undocumented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700325/what-are-the-undocumented-features-of-angular) ng-change parameter that you can use to call a function to set [$location.path](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location#path):

```
<select ... ng-model="color" ng-change="updatePath()">
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.updatePath = function() {
       $location.path(... use $scope.color here ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, although for some reason the select box then reverts to having nothing selected rather than the chosen colour>

Comment: In your controller, set $scope.color to the color parameter from the route.  Note that if you are using an array of objects to generate your select list, you'll need to set $scope.color to point to an element of that array.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297560/how-to-make-a-preselection-for-a-select-list-generated-by-angularjs) for more info.

Comment: I am using the product array to populate the select list, but am also using this (underscore) to pull unique colour titles from that array


`code`

$scope.uniqueColours = function() {
return _.chain($scope.products)
  .pluck('colour_title') 
  .flatten() 
  .unique()
  .value();
 };

`code`

so it no longer reflects the initial product array. s it not possible to set 

$scope.by_colour = $routeParams.colour_title;

Comment: The way select and ng-options work, you have to initialize your ng-model to an element of the array used in ng-options.  So in your controller, you'll need to loop through your array and find the appropriate element, then set $scope.by_colour to that.

Comment: Thanks again @Mark Rajcok, I've marked the response above as correct as it answers my original query. I was initially using ng-repeat to build my options rather than ng-options, which leads to another question but not really relevant in this thread.

Answer (score 4):

Your `<select>` element will be bound to a model with `ng-model`, which you can `$watch` and use to update either `$location.path` or `$location.search`. Personally, I'd suggest using `$location.search`: you can change **just** the parameter you want, and its a bit less work since you don't have to have knowledge of the entire path in your controller.

So assuming you have a `<select>` element like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedColor" ng-options="color for color in colors">
```

You can use `$watch` to watch your bound value and update your `$location.search`, making sure to set it to `null` if color is `undefined` or otherwise falsey (this clears the search parameter):

```
$scope.$watch('selectedColor', function (color) {
    if (color) {
      $location.search('color', color); 
    } else {
      $location.search('color', null);
    }
});
```

You might want to set up a two-way binding between the search parameter and your local model so that changes will be reflected in your `<select>`:

```
$scope.$watch('$location.search().color', function (color) {
    $scope.selectedColor = color;
});
```

Then it's just a matter of accessing `$routeParams.color` in your routed controller.

See this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/b6QuquIC8X1xCduLUnAI) for a complete working example.