# Angular select list only submits when value changed

Tags: angularjs, select

I just have a static select list with 2 options so I didn't use the ng-options parameter. This works only if the user does something to the dropdown. If they leave the value as-is, the dataItem comes through as undefined.

```
<select ng-model="dataItem.Options">
    <option value="1" ng-selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

How can I just use the default value, or why isn't my unchanged dropdown passing a value back to my controller? I've also tried to use ng-init="1" in the select tag, but that doesn't seemt to work either.

Comment: try `ng-init` on the `select` tag.

Comment: @FlorianTopf - Thanks for the reply. ng-init didn't work either. I forgot to mention that I tried that. Updating my post now.

Comment: This thread might be from help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297560/how-to-make-a-preselection-for-a-select-list-generated-by-angularjs

Comment: selected of course returns? true false | 1 | 0

Comment: @LFMarabunta Yes, but it's returning neither. It's Undefined. I'm going to try Scott's answer here this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set dataItem.Options to the value you want to select

```
     $scope.dataItem = {Options: '1'};
```

Note that the value is a string, '1', and not the number 1. THen you can remove the ng-selected.

Comment: That worked. I just had to wrap it in an if (!dataItem.Options) check first, but it does the job! Thank you!