# ng option initial value select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dynamic combo box. I want to initialise the value of all  combo boxes like this the image below is from adding  static values like this

```
  $scope.newObject ={  0 : "N/P" ,1 : "N/P",2 : "N/P",3 : "N/P"}
```

[image]

so I tried to make for on each item on the list in this code below:

```
$scope.inifonction = ["N/P","N/A","OK","KO"];
//this is the option inside the combobox
$scope.displaydata = function(index) {

    $scope.id = index;

    $http.get("/fonctions?id=" + $scope.id).success(function(data) {
        $scope.list = data;

        for(i=0;i<$scope.list.length;i++)
        {
            $scope.tab = $scope.list[i].idfonction
            //this to get the id of the list in a tab 


            console.log($scope.tab)

        //[1,6,5,3] exemple of data in the console 

        $scope.newObject ={  tab : "N/P"}
        }
    });
```

but I didn't work and it looked like this:

[image]

and here's my HTML

```
 <select  ng-model="newObject[l.idfonction]"  ng-options="  fct for fct in inifonction "  class="form-control">
```

when I insert the data am getting this as a result of that ng-model

```
Object {1: "N/A", 2: "OK", 3: "N/A", 4: "N/P", tab: "N/P"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixed my issue i hope it helps you all

```
<select ng-init="newObject[l.idfonction] = inifonction[0] " ng-model="newObject[l.idfonction]"  ng-options="  fct for fct in inifonction "  class="form-control">
```

Comment: I had a similar problem using angular material's md-select and this is how I fixed it http://stackoverflow.com/a/38639823/3836923

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to every dropdown option in the view:

`<option value = "">N/P</option>`

**UPDATE:**

I can see that you have an array specific for the initial values. You could use that to set the value as:

`<option value = "">{{inifonction[0]}}</option>` //This prints N/P

More, you could set to a scope and use it as :

`$scope.tab = "N/P";`

`<option value = "">{{tab}}</option>`

Comment: i tried to make it like that but it didn't work maybe cuzz it my ng-model= object

Comment: first thanks for answering me !  i have the data i just want to set  a default value inside the `<select>` as you can see when you ` $scope.newObject ={  0 : "N/P"}` the first element will get the value N/P but i don't want a single element to get the value i want them all since it's an object so i made a loop `$scope.newObject ={  tab : "N/P"}` and tab is the id  so i can make  ` $scope.newObject ={  0 : "N/P" , 1 : "N/P" , etc  }`