# Default dummy item with angularjs ngoptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm populating an HTML select element with options loaded from an external datasource.
This is working fine but I would like to have a default "dummy" value at the top. Eg. "--Select something--".
How can this be achieved?

```html
<select ng-Model="selectedModel" ng-options="model as model.Model__c for model in vehicleModels"></select>
```

Comment: Have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706986/empty-first-element-in-dropdown-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706986/empty-first-element-in-dropdown-list)

Comment: Thank you. I'd seen that already but it just shows me a blank option... My label is never shown.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an `ng-init` as given below.

```
<select ng-init="selectedModel=vehicleModels[0]" ng-Model="selectedModel" ng-options="model as model.Model__c for model in vehicleModels"></select>
```

and have your dummy item as the first element in the `vehicleModels` array