# AngularJs and <select>: Default selected options are removed

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I expect the following code to render a drop down list with the third option selected by default. However, when I bind the select with angularjs, the default selection disappears. Any thought?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

...

<div>
  <select id="myselection" ng-model="selectedColors">
    <option value="1" >Red</option>
     <option value="2">Blue</option>
     <option value="3" selected="selected">Green</option>
  </select>

  <div>
    Selected Colors: {{selectedColors }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TXPJZ/134/

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest way to fix your implementation is to use `ng-init`.

```
<div>
    <select id="myselection" ng-init="selectedColors=3" ng-model="selectedColors">
        <option value="1">Red</option>
        <option value="2">Blue</option>
        <option value="3">Green</option>
    </select>
    <div>Selected Colors: {{selectedColors }}</div>
</div>
```

Try it on [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TXPJZ/136/).

Comment: Probably obvious, but as it caught me out, remember to enclose the ng-init value in single quotes if its a string, eg ng-init="selectedColors='red'"

Comment: this doesn't work when you're populating the select using `ng-options="row.desc for row in affiliationTable"`
because I don't know of a way to assign the value when doing it that way, do you know how I can do that?

Comment: The official [documentation for ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit) states the following: _"The only appropriate use of ngInit for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope."_. Is there any other way to remove de 'default' value?

Answer (score 10):

Angular overrides the "selected" property when you bind the select to a model. If you inspect the rendered DOM you will find that a new item has been added:

```
<option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
```

In order to automatically select the third option you need to pre-populate the model in scope. There are a few ways to do this, including wrapping the select in a controller:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select id="myselection" ng-model="selectedColors">
        <option value="1">Red</option>
        <option value="2">Blue</option>
        <option value="3">Green</option>
    </select>
<div>Selected Colors: {{selectedColors }}</div>
```

And then defining that model in the controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectedColors = 2;
}]);
```

Here's a running example.

http://jsfiddle.net/93926/

Alternatively, you could just initialize it using ng-init such as in this example:

```
<div ng-init="selectedColors=3">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9JxqA/1/

EDIT: Removed the selected property in the first example, it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

By adding option with empty value to select and initializing selectedColors to empty string(ng-init="selectedColors=''"), we can see  'select Color' option on top  instead of having first color to be selected defaultly:

```
<div>
<select id="myselection" ng-init="selectedColors=''" ng-model="selectedColors">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Blue</option>
    <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>
<div>Selected Colors: {{selectedColors }}</div>
```

Try it on Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CodecPM/qxyckf7u/

Comment: I choose this answer. relying on ng-init itself sometimes creates temporary empty <option>.

Suggestion: add disabled="disabled" to <option> for the "Select Color".

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do only two things
1)ng-init="days='noday'"
2)ng-selected="true"

```
 <select class="filtersday" ng-init="days='noday'" ng-model="days">
 <option ng-selected="true" value="noday">--Select Day--</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use single quote to work per

```
<select ng-model="liveDataType" ng-init="liveDataType='1'" class="form-control input height" required>
    <option value="1">Running data</option>
    <option value="2">Rest Data</option>
    <option value="3">All Data</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-selected="true"

Check the below code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<select ng-model="foo" ng-app >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option ng-selected="true" value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```