# Why Can't I have multiple ng-if options in a select when using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to  include certain options in my select box if certain expressions are true and I'm finding it adds the 1st one and not the 2nd one, and this only occurs when I use ng-options
I did try this with more complex expressions but reduced to to just `ng-if="true"` to verify my suspicion , once I remove the `ng-options` both if-ng options are added.

this is my users model

```
    $scope.users = [{
        "id": "123",
        "description": "Tester",
        "name": "Jane"
    },
    {
        "id": "312",
        "description": "Dev",
        "name": "John"
    }];
```

This is my simplified select

```
<select class="fullWidth" ng-model="name_model" ng-selected="name_model"
ng-options="user.name as user.description for user in users" required>
    <option ng-if="true" value="">-- Please Select an Approver Type: --</option>
    <option ng-if="true" value="">-- Please Select One: --</option>
</select>
```

Is this a bug, is it just not allowed or am I overlooking something. I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kswCe/) that may explain better then I am here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does angularjs include an empty option in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Comment: @Fresheyeball it's not really a duplicate as I am looking to hardcode more options not remove an empty option, but I can see how they may relate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically for 2 options with `ng-if = true`, the code actually is equivalent to

```
<option value=""> Please Select an Approver Type: </option>
<option value=""> Please Select One: </option>
```

Since [ngOptions](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) accepts only a single hardcoded option,

> Optionally, a single hard-coded  element, with the value set
>   to an empty string, can be nested into the  element. This
>   element will then represent null or "not selected" option.

the 1st one will be overwritten.

Comment: so basically ng-if is no use to me in the situation?

Comment: I tried that (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kswCe/2/) ) and It seems to ignore the ng-if and still just add the first one