# how to combo box element by default as top angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am not getting value in select box every time it's showing me first element place blank.
i dont know why can any one tell me how to overcome this problem.

i am attaching problem what exactly problem that i am facing please see in image as well as sending my html.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh3tH.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWt21.png

**Html**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label  class="col-lg-3 form-label">Brand:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">

                            <select ng-show="categoryShow" class="form-control" ng-model="item.brand_id"  >
                                <option value="{{brand._id}}">{{brand.name}}</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="brand in brands" value="{{brand._id}}">{{brand.name}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <a ng-click='openBrandModel()'>
                                <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
                                Add Brand
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

data is perfectly binding everything good just not showing by default selected that value which i used out side ng-repeat directive.

In image u can see aslam name so i want by defuat its showing and remaing as a list.

**Js for setting brand and brands**

```
itemService.getCategoryAndBrand.TypeGetCategoryAndBrand({}, $cookies.token, function(response){
    if(response.brands){

        var catchBrands = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < response.brands.length; i++){
            if(response.brands[i]._id == catchSelectedBrand){
                $scope.brand = response.brands[i];

            }else{
                catchBrands.push(response.brands[i]);
            }
        }

        $rootScope.brands = catchBrands;
    }
    if(response.categories){

        var catchCategories = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < response.categories.length; i++){
            if(response.categories[i]._id == catchSelectedCategory){
                $scope.category = response.categories[i];

            }else{
                catchCategories.push(response.categories[i]);
            }
        }

        $rootScope.categories = catchCategories;

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the first option in your HTML.

```
<option value="{{brand._id}}">{{brand.name}}</option>
```

All of your options look like they come from the line below with the `ng-repeat`, and at this point there doesn't appear to be a `brand` scope variable so I would expect to see an option with blank value and name.

If you remove this first line then I expect to see the blank option disappear, though I have not tried and do not know any logic around angular or your browser putting a blank option here by default...

---

**Edit**

Actually seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654812/681102), it looks fairly possible you just need to make sure `item.brand_id` is set to the `_id` of an existing options.

Comment: ok my first option that write is basically that value which i want to show on top that's why i wrote seperated and second thing when i saw html it's showing me by default <option value="? object:00E ?"></option> this where this line come from when i am deleting explicilty in delete then working fine any idea about this thanx

Comment: i also removed first line as u told me but still i dont where it from adding this line that's its not empty sapce.
<option value="? object:00E ?"></option>

Comment: Can you post the JS where you set `brand` and `brands`?

Comment: Is `item.brand_id` initally set to `catchSelectedBrand` to set the default properly? If this is done then I suspect you can delete the line in my answer (and replace your `if(response.brands)` block with `catchBrands = response.brands` if you like). If that doesn't work then I'm not sure I have any other ideas...