# Remove Blank option from Select Option with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select

I am new to AngularJS. I searched a lot, but it does not solve my problem.

I am getting a blank option for the first time in select box.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div ng-app="MyApp1">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="feed.name" placeholder="Name" />
        <select ng-model="feed.config">
            <option ng-repeat="template in configs">{{template.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var MyApp=angular.module('MyApp1',[])
MyApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.feed = {};

      //Configuration
      $scope.configs = [
                                 {'name': 'Config 1',
                                  'value': 'config1'},
                                 {'name': 'Config 2',
                                  'value': 'config2'},
                                 {'name': 'Config 3',
                                  'value': 'config3'}
                               ];
      //Setting first option as selected in configuration select
      $scope.feed.config = $scope.configs[0].value;
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. 
How can I get this solved? Here is [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ugkPr/1/)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

For reference : [Why does angularjs include an empty option in select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654812/2353403)?

> The empty `option` is generated when a value referenced by `ng-model` doesn't exist in a set of options passed to `ng-options`. This happens to prevent accidental model selection: AngularJS can see that the initial model is either undefined or not in the set of options and don't want to decide model value on its own.
>
> In short: the empty option means that no valid model is selected (by valid I mean: from the set of options). You need to select a valid model value to get rid of this empty option.

Change your code like this

```js
var MyApp=angular.module('MyApp1',[])
MyApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.feed = {};

  //Configuration
  $scope.feed.configs = [
    {'name': 'Config 1',
     'value': 'config1'},
    {'name': 'Config 2',
     'value': 'config2'},
    {'name': 'Config 3',
     'value': 'config3'}
  ];
  //Setting first option as selected in configuration select
  $scope.feed.config = $scope.feed.configs[0].value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp1">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="feed.name" placeholder="Name" />
    <!-- <select ng-model="feed.config">
<option ng-repeat="template in configs">{{template.name}}</option>
</select> -->
    <select ng-model="feed.config" ng-options="template.value as template.name for template in feed.configs">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ugkPr/2/)

**UPDATE (Dec 31, 2015)**

If You don't want to set a default value and want to remove blank option,

```
<select ng-model="feed.config" ng-options="template.value as template.name for template in feed.configs">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Choose</option>
</select>
```

And in JS no need to initialize value.

<s>`$scope.feed.config = $scope.feed.configs[0].value;`</s>

Comment: an explanation would really help

Comment: Why is moving `configs` from `$scope` to `$scope.feed` necessary?

Comment: So... what does it mean when I do have a valid value and it still gives me a blank line instead of using that option? model - 0, options 0, 50, 100 - select starts on blank line

Answer (score 57):

While all the suggestions above are working, sometimes I need to have an empty selection (showing placeholder text) when initially enter my screen. So, to prevent select box from adding this empty selection at the beginning (or sometimes at the end) of my list I am using this trick:

## HTML Code

```
<div ng-app="MyApp1">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="feed.name" placeholder="Name" />
        <select ng-model="feed.config" ng-options="template.value as template.name for template in feed.configs" placeholder="Config">
            <option value="" selected hidden />
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you have defined this empty option, so select box is happy, but you keep it hidden.

Comment: +1 for the only answer that does not initialize the model to the first option in the list.
My weird implementation needed the select list to start blank but not include the blank option when the select list is clicked.  This is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UKySp/

You needed to set your initial model value to the actual object:

```
$scope.feed.config = $scope.configs[0];
```

And update your select to look like this:

```
<select ng-model="feed.config" ng-options="item.name for item in configs">
```

Answer (score 14):

Another method to resolve is by making use of: **`$first`** in `ng-repeat`

Usage:

```
<select ng-model="feed.config">
    <option ng-repeat="template in configs" ng-selected="$first">{{template.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**References**:

*ngSelected* : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

*$first* : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways like -

```
<select ng-init="feed.config = options[0]" ng-model="feed.config"
        ng-options="template.value as template.name for template in feed.configs">
</select>
```

Or

```
$scope.feed.config = $scope.configs[0].name;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is kind of a workaround but works like a charm. Just add `<option value="" style="display: none"></option>` as a filler. Like in:

```
<select size="4" ng-model="feed.config" ng-options="template.value as template.name for template in feed.configs">
       <option value="" style="display: none"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: this does not hide the default option in IE I guess

Comment: have not specifically tested that in IE

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to remove the blank space use ng-show and you are done! No need to initialize value in JS.

```
<select ng-model="SelectedStatus" ng-options="x.caption for x in statusList">
    <option value="" ng-show="false"></option>
</select>`
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this. 
You forget about the value inside option. 
Before you assign the ng-model.  It must have a value.  Only then it doesn't get the undefined value.

```
<div ng-app="MyApp1">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="feed.name" placeholder="Name" />
     <select ng-model="feed">
        <option ng-repeat="template in configs" value="template.value">{{template.name}}    
 </option>
    </select>
    </div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
 var MyApp=angular.module('MyApp1',[])
 MyApp.controller('MyController',function($scope) {  
      $scope.feed = 'config1';      
      $scope.configs = [
         {'name': 'Config 1', 'value': 'config1'},
         {'name': 'Config 2', 'value': 'config2'},
         {'name': 'Config 3', 'value': 'config3'}
      ];
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **ng-value** instead of **value**.

```
$scope.allRecs = [{"text":"hello"},{"text":"bye"}];
$scope.X = 0;
```

and then in html file should be like:

```
<select ng-model="X">  
     <option ng-repeat="oneRec in allRecs track by $index" ng-value="$index">{{oneRec.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer to this question was using `<option value="" selected hidden />` as it was proposed by @RedSparkle plus adding `ng-if="false"` to work in IE.

So my full option is (has differences with what I wrote before, but this does not matter because of ng-if):

`<option value="" ng-if="false" disabled hidden></option>`

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked for me.

```
<select ng-init="mybasketModel = basket[0]" ng-model="mybasketModel">
        <option ng-repeat="item in basket" ng-selected="$first">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Also check whether you have any falsy value or not.
Angularjs will insert an empty option if you do have falsy value. 
I struggled for 2 days just due to falsy value.
I hope it will be helpful for someone.

I had options as [0, 1] and initially I was set the model to 0 due to that it was inserted empty option. 
Workaround for this was ["0" , "1"].