# Select box in Angular adding extra blank option

Tags: angularjs

I have a select/drop-down box in my Angularjs app:

```
<select ng-model="places">
  <option value="1">London</option>
  <option value="2">Paris</option>
  <option value="3">Madrid</option>
  <option value="4">Athens</option>
</select>
```

but in the HTML page there is an extra blank `option` added above the London option. When I remove `ng-model` then it renders as I would expect (i.e. 4 options with London showing by default). Is this normal?

Comment: You can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738953/angular-js-remove-blank-option-from-select-option

Answer (score 0):

if the value of ng-model i.e. **places** does not match with the option values than this extra blank option is generated and by default selected. 
You need to set ng-model value equals to one of the options or if you do not want any value to be selected by default create one more option with value blank

```
 <option value="">Select</option>
```

and set ng-model i.e. **places**  to "" in the controller.

Answer (score -1):

In your case you can try this:

```js
 var app = angular.module("Demo", []);
 app.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
   
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Demo">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <select ng-model="places" ng-init="places=1">
      <option value="1">London</option>
      <option value="2">Paris</option>
      <option value="3">Madrid</option>
      <option value="4">Athens</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks.