# Remove the empty object value at the bottom of your select (that gets triggered by ng-repeat)

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5.3

My code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Productgroup</label>
    <select id="product_group_id" name="product_group_id" class="form-control" ng-model="productGroup" ng-change="changedType(val)"> 
            <option style="display: none" value="">Choose a productgroup</option>
        @foreach ($product_groups as $product_group)
            <option value="{{$product_group->id}}">{{$product_group->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Product</label>
    <select id="product_id" name="product_id" class="form-control" ng-model="form.product_id">
        <option style="display: none" value="">Choose a product</option>                        
            <option value="@{{product.id}}" ng-repeat="product in products">@{{product.name}}<option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The product group select basically filters the next select; products.

I keep getting this empty option value included at the bottom of my product select options, like so:

```
<option value=""></option>
```

I've already used `<option style="display: none" value="">Choose product</option>` to remove the first empty option value in my product select.

**Update:**

Use ng-options instead of ng-repeat, like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Product</label>
    <select id="product_id" name="product_id" class="form-control" ng-options="product.id as product.name for product in products" ng-model="form.product_id">
        <option style="display: none" value="">Choose a product</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Just check by a if statement before outputting the `<option>` tag. Like `if(!empty($product_group->name)) {}`

Comment: @if(!empty($product_group->name)) 
                                <option value="@{{product.id}}" ng-repeat="product in products">@{{product.name}}<option>
                            @endif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would say your ng-repeat is in the wrong place, probably should use the  standard angular way (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select):
`<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id" ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>`
then if you want to remove the empty/first element, have a look at this [Angular JS Remove Blank option from Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738953/angular-js-remove-blank-option-from-select-option)

Comment: Does this only count for the product select?

Comment: it should generate a <select> full of <options> for you.

Comment: I'm talking about the second select; the select were I choose products.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the data isn't empty, for example:

```
<select id="product_group_id" name="product_group_id" class="form-control" ng-model="productGroup" ng-change="changedType(val)"> 
        <option style="display: none" value="">Choose a productgroup</option>
    foreach ($product_groups as $product_group)
       if (!empty($product_group->name) && !empty($product_group->id)) {
        <option value="{{$product_group->id}}">{{$product_group->name}}</option>
       }
    endforeach
</select>
```

But I think you should try to find where this empty line come from to avoid further problems