# Angularjs, select Box create blank option at first always

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model, jquery-selectbox

I got some problems with `selectbox`.

In my original code, I receive an object through `$http` calling, and that is like below.

```
[
    {key:'user_id', value:'ID'},
    {key:'user_name', value:'Name'},
    {key:'user_gender', value:'Gender'},
    {key:'user_phone', value:'Phone'},
    {key:'user_email', value:'Email'},
    {key:'user_birth', value:'Birthday'},
];
```

When I tried to put values of this object into `option`, it made 'blank option' automatically.

To solve this, I saw two posts

[Angular JS Remove Blank option from Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738953/angular-js-remove-blank-option-from-select-option)

[Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

but any solutions of these could not help me.

How can I fix this?

Here's my fiddle.

[Select box create blank option](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/3pp61gny/3/)

I'll wait some handsome or pretty developers who will solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This

HTML Code -

```
<select ng-options="opt as opt.value for opt in searchOpt.option" ng-model="searchOpt.selected">
    </select>
```

The ngOptions attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of  elements for the  element using the array or object obtained by evaluating the ngOptions comprehension expression

Working [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3pp61gny/9/)

Comment: oh my... you just saved someone's life.. thanks! But I got a question. Now, select box default value is last value of option. I want to set first value to default. can you fix this too?

Comment: Please go through this link will resolved your issue https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: @CanetRobern :  I've update the Ans. please look into this. hope this will resolve your issue https://jsfiddle.net/3pp61gny/9/

Comment: I don't know why your fiddle works fantastic, but not mine.. T.T

Answer (score 3):

```
<select ng-model="itemSelected">
  <option
      ng-repeat="item in data" value="{{ item.key }}"
      ng-selected="{{item.key === itemSelected}}">
    {{ item.value }}
  </option>
</select>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/QthDhkvku8UvcVHaWcGG?p=preview

Check the code. Use ng-selected in your option for selected first element.

Comment: thanks to your suggestion, but I think my problem has occurred by using `$q`. If put `$q` into your code, maybe same problem will occur.