# How to disable blank option in select AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the answers could help with my requirement.

I have a piece of code

```
<select ng-change ="loadHomePage()" ng-model="selectedPage" ng-options="x for x in pages"></select>
```

And my javascript looks something like this,

```
for (var i = 1; i<=response.data.pages; i++)
{
    $scope.pages.push(i);
}
```

My problem is that every time I run this code, it gives me a blank option. Which is fine, I can disable it from view by,

```
<option value="" hidden>
```

But my ng-model is such that after I select an option, the value gets reset to the default blank, i.e. null.

I want to take the option that I selected and keep ng-model set to that value. So it doesn't change any value for me.

I thought I could introduce another variable here, which could store the value of selectedPage, so it won't matter if the value of selected page gets changed, but it would be great if someone could tell me if there is a direct way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular JS Remove Blank option from Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738953/angular-js-remove-blank-option-from-select-option)

Comment: @VipulSolanki Hey Vipul! I had previously checked out that answer, but couldn't find what I wanted!

Comment: try this: `$scope.selectedPage = $scope.pages[0]` after loop

Comment: Then what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of want to say that try to use [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) and avoid `for` loop.
Also don't get your logic `$scope.pages.push(i);`, means are pushing the index?.
Please replace below answer and let me know if that's not what you want.

```
angular.forEach(response.data.pages, function(value, key) {
  if(value != ''){
      $scope.pages.push(value);
  }
}, $scope);
```