# How we use ng-repeat on option tag

Tags: angularjs

hello I am using the drop down option which are fetch from DB. and i made an array as below

```
var _arr = new Array()
_arr = [{className:5,avg:40},{className:6,avg:50},{className:7,avg:40}}]
```

in html inside the select tag

```
<option ng-repeat="flds in _arr" value="{{flds.className}}"></option>
```

here expected output will be option tag should have 3 elements. But i got 4 elements

Comment: your _arr has an unexpected closing curly brackets at the end

Comment: Seems like this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select

Comment: sorry but my array  is declared correctly in my code. I am sorry I had made mistake here. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ng-options` attribute on your `<select>` tag:

```
<select ng-options="flds.avg as flds.className for flds in _arr"></select>
```

[More info](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)