# issues with select field's empty option

Tags: angularjs

We are facing multiple issues with select field's empty option.

My rendering code is as follows:

```
&#60;select ng-switch-when="select" id="{{field.name}}" ng-model=data[field.name] >
&#60;option ng-repeat="option in field.options" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.description}}
&#60;/select>
```

Here our UI is dynamically generated and options also populates dynamically using REST APIs. The Select field is bound to a data object that also populated using REST calls that might have blank value initially.

Issue

1. It automatically adds a empty option where it is not required and disappear after selecting any non-empty option.
2. Also it is showing following error for few select fields

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'prop' of undefined
>       at selectDirective.link.ngModelCtrl.$render (lib/angular/angular.js:20165:47)
>               at Object.ngModelWatch (lib/angular/angular.js:16734:14)
>               at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (lib/angular/angular.js:11800:40)
>               at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (lib/angular/angular.js:12061:24)
>               at done (lib/angular/angular.js:7843:45)
>               at completeRequest (lib/angular/angular.js:8026:7)
>               at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (lib/angular/angular.js:7982:11)

I have doubt that is use following code in angular

```
function setupAsSingle(scope, selectElement, ngModelCtrl, selectCtrl) {
ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
var viewValue = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;

  if (selectCtrl.hasOption(viewValue)) {
    if (unknownOption.parent()) unknownOption.remove();
    selectElement.val(viewValue);
    if (viewValue === '') emptyOption.prop('selected', true); // to make IE9 happy
  } else {
    if (isUndefined(viewValue) && emptyOption) {
      selectElement.val('');
    } else {
      selectCtrl.renderUnknownOption(viewValue);
    }
  }
```

...

and it break at this line

```
if (viewValue === '') emptyOption.prop('selected', true); // to make IE9 happy
```

because the empty option is provided by REST API at later stage and not available till initial rendering.

Please provide some suggestion for implementation and some alternate approach.

P.S : I can not use ng-option with select as it emit indexed values and I need actual values for some DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I would first read over how to do data-ng-options (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select) because your select will cause you a bit of issues. Here's how you could move your code around:

```
<span data-ng-switch-when="select">
    <select id="{{field.name }}" data-ng-model="data[field.name]" data-ng-options="option.value as option.description for option in field.options></select>
</span>
```

Secondly, the reason that the blank option is selected is because data[field.name] is not set to a value that's present in option.value. You need to set it in your controller so the blank option goes away. You can see a similar question here: [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)