# Angularjs: default value when current option not in domain of select

Tags: angularjs, select, default

I have cascading select where the value in the first decided what should be the option of others.

When I change the value of the first select so that the currently selected value in one other is no more a possible choice, I get a null (empty) choice. In place, I want to get a default, not null, value (of course, I don't want to reset to a default value is the choice is still legit).

I looked to (rather) similar question like [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select) but is does not seem to work, perhaps because my options are not predefined but generated on change.

I set-up a jsfiddle with the actual code: http://jsfiddle.net/sXu9a/

1. choose 2 hours or greater on the first select
2. chosse 1 in the second select (start hour)
3. choose back less than 1 hour in the first select

=> the second select display a empty option, and the "startHour" model still contains the last selected value (which is no more a valid choice). I really want to update the ng-model for that option to be reseted to 0.

In fact, I would like to be able to encode the condition: "if current model value for selected option is not in the set of possible value, reassign to model a default value (0)". So I tried a "onChange" like that:

```
   $scope.onChangeInterval = function() {
     if(jQuery.inArray($scope.agentSchedule.startHour, $scope.startHours() ) ) {
       $scope.agentSchedule.startHour = $scope.startHours()[0];
     }
   }
```

But that does not seem to work.

Any idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

So, it happens that the "onChange" solution DOES work, as long as you don't make typos in the variable of your name. So with the following code (onChange is called on the first select):

```
$scope.onChangeInterval = function() {
 if(jQuery.inArray($scope.agentSchedule.startHour, $scope.hours() ) ) {
   $scope.agentSchedule.startHour = $scope.hours()[0];
 }
```

}

Sorry for the noise!