# Select in directive with transclude not changing parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zorro/U8HpP/2/

Below code does not work.
If I remove the transclude and template, it works just as intended. 
What am I missing?

```
    <div ng-app="example">
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="car in carsOwned">
             <h3>Owned car: {{car.brand}}</h3>

            <div example-select ng-model="car">
                <select ng-model="car" ng-options="carType.brand for carType in carTypes"></select>
                <p>Why doesn't the select alter the owned car?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



function TodoCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.carTypes = [{
            brand: 'BMW',
            value: 'bmw'
        }, {
            brand: 'Mercedes',
            value: 'me'
        }, {
            brand: 'Fiat',
            value: 'fi'
        }];

        $scope.carsOwned = [$scope.carTypes[0]];

    }

    angular.module('example', []).directive('exampleSelect', function () {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                car: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                console.log('alive');
            },
            template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding to `carsOwned[$index]` instead of `car` works:

```
<select ng-model="carsOwned[$index]" ng-options="carType.brand for carType in carTypes"></select>
```

But you will have trouble if multiple cars are owned, because `carsOwned` may contain duplicates and break `ng-repeat`.  To fix this, add a tracking expression:

```
<div ng-repeat="car in carsOwned track by $index">
```

Here is an update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U8HpP/5/

Answer (score 2):

`ng-transclude` creates a child scope, so you need to set an object member in order to access the parent scope variable

---

**EDIT**

In order to avoid having an empty option placed in your select options, you also need to set an initial value as per [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

---

```
<h3>Owned car: {{car.value.brand}}</h3>

<div example-select>
    <select ng-model="car.value" ng-options="carType.brand for carType in carTypes" ng-init="car.value=carTypes[0]"></select>
</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcolepsy/zd7N6/)