# Angular data-bound <select> is empty

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

Following is a dropdown data-bound with AngualarJS:

```
   <select name="lineCode" class="form-control input-sm"
        ng-model="monitoringProbe.tdmCapture.selectedTDMCard.layer1Properties.lineCode"
        ng-options="l.id as l.name for l in monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.lineCodes"
                    required >
   </select>
```

I populate the ng-options as follows:

```
 virtualServerMonitoringProbeService.comboProperties().query({},{itemType:1, interfaceType: interfaceType}).$promise.then(
            function(result){
                monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.lineCodes = result;
            },
            function(error){
                messageNotificationFactory.setNotification('error', error.data.message);
            }
        );
```

According to the following post, when there's no value in ng-model to match the items in the dropdown.
[Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Therefore I force the first element in the list to be the selected value, as follows:

```
     virtualServerMonitoringProbeService.comboProperties().query({},{itemType:1, interfaceType: interfaceType}).$promise.then(
            function(result){
                monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.lineCodes = result;
                tdmCapture.selectedTDMCard.layer1Properties.lineCode = monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.lineCodes[0];
            },
            function(error){
                messageNotificationFactory.setNotification('error', error.data.message);
            }
        );
```

But still the dropdown selection is empty. At run time this is how it looks like:

```
<select name="lineCode" class="form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-model="monitoringProbe.tdmCapture.selectedTDMCard.layer1Properties.lineCode" ng-options="l.id as l.name for l in monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.lineCodes" required="">
   <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
   <option value="0">AMI</option>
    <option value="1">B8ZS</option>
</select>
```

Anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Try `tdmCapture.selectedTDMCard.layer1Properties.lineCode = monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.lineCodes[0].id`, Youre missing `.id` SInce you have mentioned `l.id as l.name` in your ng-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the syntax *"`select` as `label` for `value` in `array`"* in your ngoption `ng-options="l.id as l.name for l in monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.lineCodes"` You need your ng-model to hold the id of the selected item for default selection. But it seems like instead you are setting the object ngModel.

Try changing:-

```
    tdmCapture.selectedTDMCard.layer1Properties.lineCode = 
                   monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.lineCodes[0];
```

to

```
 tdmCapture.selectedTDMCard.layer1Properties.lineCode = 
                    monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.lineCodes[0].id;
```

*Possible you are also missing `monitoringProbe` in the model?*

Comment: Thanks, PSL. I really had overlooked that. monitoringProbe - this is declared in the parent factory, and is accessible.