# ng-option default value always blank

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I cannot for the life of me set the default value for my select.  It's always blank. Ugh.

```
<div ng-controller="quickComposeController">
    <div id="QuickComposeEmail">
        <form id="quickComposeForm">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Set email preferences</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <select ng-init="selected=selected[0]" ng-model="selected" ng-options="o.value as o.name for o in optionsObject">

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Compose Email">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my controller:

```
app.controller('quickComposeController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.selected = [{name : "Use Default Mail Client", value : "mailto"}];

    $scope.optionsObject = [
        {name : "Use Default Mail Client", value : "mailto"},
        {name : "Gmail", value : "gmail"},
        {name : "Yahoo", value : "yahoo"},
        {name : "Hotmail", value : "hotmail"},
        {name : "AOL", value : "aol"}
    ]

}]);
```

I'm only writing this down at the bottom because stackoverflow is telling me my post is mostly code and I need more text.  Have a wonderful day everyone!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does angularjs include an empty option in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select should be:

```
<select ng-init="selected=selected[0].value" ng-model="selected" ng-options="o.value as o.name for o in optionsObject">
```

Here's the [associated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/z7QtYx2f8BLiD8JriIpq?p=preview).

The point to note is that you have to specify not only the right index but also the `value` property in it, since your options are based on `value`.

Comment: thank you... feel silly for not having figured this out.