# ng-change not firing when empty select option is removed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select list in angluarJs, which I have removed the default empty value from (using the answer from this question [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)).

Now, when I try and select the first option, the ng-change method doesn't fire. I understand why, the value hasn't changed. However, the ng-change method is calling a function which hides the select element, so I can't click on the 2nd element and then the 1st element again.

I've tried adding an ng-click event, but this responds to any click in the select, even if its not on an option.

is there any way to get around this?

cheers

Comment: why you want to select the first option again if it is already selecetd

Comment: some context, this is a post code lookup, so use enters a post code, and I display a list of possible addresses. I don't want the blank line to appear in the select list, but can't actually select the first element, as this may not be the correct address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured this out, its not perfect, but it does what I need.

just add

```
<option hidden value=""></option>
```

inside the select tags.

Answer (score 0):

We have had the same issue.  To solve this problem we used [angularjs ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).

This will allow the user to type in the postal code then you can query for a list of possible addresses and the user can pick from there.  I hope this helps as it has worked great for us.

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately I don't think that's going to do what I need. The spec for this is pretty rigid.