# How to make model attribute be expanded by AngularJS to options in select element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

I need to access and manage `options` in `select` element by AngularJS. I am passing it to JSP using `model.addAttribute("environmentsMap", getEnvironments());`. For some reason one of options ends up as

`<option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>`

although on server side there are no empty or null elements. How to fix it?

```
<ng-form id="form" name="form" ng-class="{'has-error': test.$invalid}" class="form-group">
<select name="environment" id="environment" name="environment_name" class="form-control" ng-model="environment" required>
                <c:forEach var="environment" items="${environmentsMap}">
                    <option value="${environment.key}"
                        ${environment.key && environment.key == "TEST" ? 'selected' : ''}>${environment.key}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
 </ng-form>
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: have you passed data through ng-init

Comment: no, data is being passed using standard Spring MVC approach

Comment: have you look in this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select