# AngularJS setting dummy option element before valid ajax data arrives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As I understand AngularJS sets default value when using `ng-model` directive. I need to populate select element with only valid options which retrieved by `$http.get`. The problem is that on top of all valid elements I have one dummy element vith value `?`. **How to get rid of it?**

```
<select  id="environment" name="environment_name" ng-model="environment"  ng-options="e.name for e in ENVIRONMENTS" required>
                </select>

$scope.ENVIRONMENTS = [];
$http.get("/getEnvironments").success(function(data){
       data.forEach(function(el){
           $scope.ENVIRONMENTS.push(el);
       });
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.showErrorMsg("Cannot get ENVIRONMENTS.");
    });
 $scope.environment = $scope.ENVIRONMENTS[0];
```

Comment: Seems like this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add temporary value to your  $scope.ENVIRONMENTS array ie:

```
 $scope.ENVIRONMENTS = [{name:"Please wait"}];
```

and delete it after you get data from your backed

```
$scope.ENVIRONMENTS.shift()
```

#### Please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $http) {


  $scope.ENVIRONMENTS = [{
    name: "Please wait"
  }];
  $http.get("/getEnvironments").then(function(data) {
    $scope.ENVIRONMENTS.shift()
    data.forEach(function(el) {

      $scope.ENVIRONMENTS.push(el);
    })

   //set default value after you get data from backend
   $scope.environment = $scope.ENVIRONMENTS[0];

  }, function(data) {

    $scope.showErrorMsg("Cannot get ENVIRONMENTS.");
  });
  $scope.environment = $scope.ENVIRONMENTS[0];

  $scope.showErrorMsg = function(msg) {

    console.log(msg);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    
    <select id="environment" name="environment_name" ng-model="environment" ng-options="e.name for e in ENVIRONMENTS" required>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you prefer `.then` over `.success`?

Comment: @RCola I'm not sure, just habit

Comment: @RCola add that $scope.environment = $scope.ENVIRONMENTS[0]; after you get data from your backend please see updated code

Comment: My script is right before closing `body` tag. I cannot move it. I think that causes the problem....

Comment: @RCola you don't have to move it please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/eEJXlbuiYkku0vgUj44v?p=preview