# ng-select will always show up one empty option

Tags: angularjs

My code is as below:

```
<select ng-model="timeModel" class="col-sm-1">
    <option>10:30</option>
    <option>15:30</option>
</select>
```

And the web page will be like this:

[image]

Is there anything incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of timeModel? Does it equal either of the options you have provided? If it does not then it will equal a blank option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does angularjs include an empty option in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Comment: In js file, $scope.timeModel = "08:00". But seems that this timeMoedel did not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with a `SELECT` element if none of the options provided equal the value in `ng-model` then it will create a **blank option** to represent the current state of the model.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GordyD/oov2hetn/) to demonstrate this behaviour.

It would help if you displayed the value of `timeModel` in your view to see what value this is set to. You could then inspect what the underlying value is and why it is not behaving as you intended it to.