# First item in dropdown is blank when filtering in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm filtering in my ng-options this is my code in my html

```
 <select class="form-control" id="selectType" ng-model="user.type" ng-init="user.type= types[0]">
 <option ng-repeat="type in types" value="{{type}}">{{type}}</option>
 </select>

<select class="form-control" ng-model="user.fullname" ng-options="employee as fullName(employee) for employee in employees | filter: user.type">
```

then in my controller I have this code

```
$scope.types = ['admin','encoder','checker','cashier']; 

var getEmployees = function () {
    $http.get(httpHost + '/employees').success( function (data) {
      if(data.length !== 0){
        $scope.employees =  $scope.sortData(data,'emp_fname');
        $scope.user.fullname = $scope.employees[0];
        console.log("Employees:");
        console.log($scope.employees);
      }else{
        $scope.noEmployees = true;
      }
    }).error(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };

  getEmployees();
```

it will filter it correctly but leave a blank in the first item in the dropdown
my result is like this one http://jsfiddle.net/sheppe/EeL9y/

Comment: Where do you get `employees`? How is it populated? What does it look like in a raw form (i.e. what items are in it)?

Comment: there I edited the question :D

Comment: I highly doubt that it has any relation to Angular, AFAIU that's just the behavior of `<select>`. It was already asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the behavior of select. If you want to set an initial (non-blank) value, you can do something like this-

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="user.fullname"
ng-options="employee as fullName(employee) for employee in employees | filter: user.type">
<option value=''>Text you want to display</option>
</select>
```