# How to use ng-options in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

The select element is not bound as expected.

**html:**

```
<select ng-model="SelectedPage" 
 ng-change="ShowPageResult();" ng-options="o for o in PageNumbers">
</select>
```

**ctrl.js:**

```
function BindPageNumbers() {        
        $scope.PageNumbers = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= 2) ; i++) {
            $scope.PageNumbers.push(i);
        }      
    }
```

**output:**

```
<option value="0"label="1">1</option>
<option value="1" label="2">2</option>
```

if i put `$scope.PageNumbers.push(i.toString());`, then the output is

```
<option value="?"label=""></option>
<option value="0" label="1">1</option>
<option value="1" label="2">2</option>
```

**expected:**

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

what should be done to get the desired o/p : http://jsfiddle.net/s222904f/

Comment: Arrays are zero based so the output is exactly as expected.  If you want to have a value other than what you get, you can push an object with a label and a value and use the "select as" part of the ngOptions expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/khwuv4Lj/

Per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654812/771928), the empty option exists because the

```
ng-model="SelectedPage"
```

line binds it to an empty string. You can avoid this by setting the default value if the select in the scope.

**Edit: Plnkr was updated to fix the OP's comment.**

[image]

Comment: The values are 0 and 1 for the options. They should be 1 & 2

Comment: @Qwerty Fixed the fiddle for future people referencing this per your comment.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller:

```
$scope.PageNumbers = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 2 ; i++) {
    $scope.PageNumbers.push({ id: i, value: i });
}
```

In your view:

```
<select ng-model="SelectedPage"    
    ng-options="o.id for o in PageNumbers track by o.value"></select>
```

Comment: @Qwerty That's cause he changed your binding structure in his answer and you can't use that line when binding to an object.