# AngularJS How to remove empty option - Blank from Select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hoping for your help.

I am getting a blank option for the first time in select box. 
**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="DispAngleApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
  <p><select size="1" ng-change="change_val(angle3)" ng-model="angle3" ng-init="angle3='0'">
                <option ng-repeat ="option in data" value="{{option.corner1}}, {{option.corner2}}">{{option.name}}</option>
            </select></p>
</div>
```

**AngularJS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function AppCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
      id: 0,
      corner1: '0',
      corner2: '0',
      name: '---Выберите ТК---'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      corner1: '0',
      corner2: '0',
      name: 'ТКР-6(01)'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      corner1: '90',
      corner2: '99',
      name: 'ТКР-6(02)'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      corner1: '180',
      corner2: '270',
      name: 'ТКР-6(03)'
    }
  ];
}
```

How can I fix that problem?
Thanks.

**EDITED:**
Demo of a problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/2203/
I need both values of value option.

**UPDATE:**http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/2227/
Here it is my code. I tried to update chosen value on all fields and turn the image on selected angle and with help of Danny Fardy Jhonston Bermúdez I've fixed the problem, thanks.

Comment: I've updated my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using:

```
ng-options="option as option.name for option in data"
```

Where «option» contains the object that you selected.

**Updated:**

By using:

```
$scope.change_val = function(angle3) {
      $scope.angle1 = angle3.corner1;
      $scope.angle2 = angle3.corner2;
      console.log(angle3.corner1 + ", " + angle3.corner2);
};
```

You'll have access to the properties of the selected object, so easily can show in your text box fields correctly.

Then:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('DispAngleApp', []);

myApp.controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
      id: 0,
      corner1: '0',
      corner2: '0',
      name: '---Choose TC---'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      corner1: '0',
      corner2: '0',
      name: 'ТКР-6(01)'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      corner1: '90',
      corner2: '99',
      name: 'ТКР-6(02)'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      corner1: '180',
      corner2: '270',
      name: 'ТКР-6(03)'
    }];
    $scope.angle3 = $scope.data[0];
    $scope.change_val = function(angle3) {
      $scope.angle1 = angle3.corner1;
      $scope.angle2 = angle3.corner2;
      console.log(angle3.corner1 + ", " + angle3.corner2);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="DispAngleApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
  <p><span class="alfa">&alpha; = {{angle1}}&deg;</span>
  </p>
  <input type="text" id="ang_1" maxlength="3" onfocus="this.value = parseInt(value) || ''" onblur="this.value = parseInt(value) || '0'" ng-change="minmax(angle1, 0, 360) || 0" ng-model="angle1" ng-init="angle1='0'">
  <br>
  <p><span class="beta">&beta; = {{angle2}}&deg;</span>
  </p>
  <input type="text" id="ang_2" maxlength="3" onfocus="this.value = parseInt(value) || ''" onblur="this.value = parseInt(value) || '0'" ng-change="minmax2(angle2, 0, 360) || 0" ng-model="angle2" ng-init="angle2='0'">
  <br>
  <p>
    <select size="1" ng-change="change_val(angle3)" ng-model="angle3" ng-options="option as option.name for option in data">
    </select>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: thak you for help, your answer helped me to solve the problem. here it is my code where i used your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/2227/

Answer (score 2):

> The empty option is generated when a value referenced by `ng-model` doesn't exist in a set of options passed to `ng-options`. This happens to prevent accidental model selection: [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)can see that the initial model is either `undefined` or not in the set of options and don't want to decide model value on its own.

[Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

**After looking into this, as far as I understand, there is no support for complex value types**. The best solution **around this** in my opinion is to look up the value given the id. The id must be unique in order to look up the values.

See http://jsfiddle.net/61xtxy6a/

**Markup**:

```
<div ng-app="DispAngleApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
  <select size="1" ng-change="change_val(angle3)" ng-model="angle3">
    <option ng-repeat ="option in data" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <button ng-click="getValue()">Get value.</button>
</div>
```

**The controller**:

```
$scope.data = [{
    id: 0,
    corner1: '0',
    corner2: '0',
    name: '---Выберите ТК---'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    corner1: '0',
    corner2: '0',
    name: 'ТКР-6(01)'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    corner1: '90',
    corner2: '99',
    name: 'ТКР-6(02)'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    corner1: '180',
    corner2: '270',
    name: 'ТКР-6(03)'
  }
];
$scope.angle3 = '0';

$scope.getValue = function() {
  var value = $scope.data[$scope.angle3].corner1 + ',' + $scope.data[$scope.angle3].corner2;
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've read about that, but how can I fix? I have complex value, so the Blank appears.

Comment: your solution is right if you want to use <button>, but that is not my variant. if you want to use array of values, just use <ng-oprion> like in Answer and put your function in controller. here it is my code: jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/2227 thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You should likely use:

```
$scope.angle3 = "0, 0";
```

Since that is the value compared by [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)here (the value of your `<option>`).