# Error with Select (Angular JS) -> It shows blank option not the real first option (look screenshots)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

English is not my first language so i don't really know how to explain what is going on with words so i'll just use images :)

I have this select here:

```
 <select class="form-control input-lg"  name="page" ng-model="campaign.page" ng-required="true">
              <option selected disabled>{{"Select the fan page"|i18n}}...</option>
              <option ng-repeat="page in fanPages" value="{{page}}">{{page.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

And everything works fine, except that the disabled option "Select fan page" is not showing (check the screen shot)

[How it looks when i click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMIrT.png)

[How was it supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ38R.png)

Anyone knows why this is happening? i can't figure it out. I'm using Angular js, bootstrap

It is generating this HTML

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
```

Why is it generating automatically this option with "?" value?

Comment: @FarzadYZ i am not using trustAsHtml in this page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was a HTML or CSS problem, but turns out it was Angular JS.
By doing this I was able to solve the problem:

```
 <select class="form-control input-lg"  name="page" ng-model="campaign.page" ng-required="true"
              ng-options="page.name for page in fanPages track by page.id">
            </select>
```

> The empty option is generated when a value referenced by ng-model doesn't exist in a set of options passed to ng-options. This happens to prevent accidental model selection: AngularJS can see that the initial model is either undefined or not in the set of options and don't want to decide model value on its own.

[Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)