# AngularJS dropdown default value is blank

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying data from a database in a table.  One of the table columns stores true/false.  I am displaying this column as a drop down, but the value is not defaulting to the database value.  The default is blank.

JS

```
$scope.options = [{ label: 'false', val: false }, { label: 'true', val: true }];
```

$scope.usersList = users

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat = "user in usersList">
 <td>
                    <select ng-model="user.admin"
                            ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
                        <option value="{{user.admin}}">{{user.admin}}</option>
                    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Page Source

```
<td>
                    <select ng-model="user.admin" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"><option value="?" selected="selected"></option><option label="false" value="object:15">false</option><option label="true" value="object:16">true</option></select>
                </td>
```

Comment: Is `user.admin` populated? Since that is the model, that is what will be set as default, if it's empty, the default value will be empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does angularjs include an empty option in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Comment: Yes, if I only print user.admin, I see the right value.  But if I use a drop down it will not set to that value.

Answer (score 0):

By default the select ng-option is blank. you can initialise it:

```
$scope.user.admin = options[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, ensure user.admin has a value that maps to a value in your ng-options to set a default value and handle the blank option.

[Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize $scope.user.admin like this:

```
$scope.user.admin = true;
```

or like this

```
$scope.user.admin = false;
```

Have a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/r9sb53zv/

Comment: But that doesn't solve my problem.  I want to set it to what is stored in the db and not default it to any value.  I am displaying rows from a table and one of the column stores either true or false.  In the drop down, it should default to the database value and allow the use to change it by selecting the other option in the drop down.

Comment: Do a little reading man! I just gave you idea. Get the value from the database and set it to $scope.user.admin.

Comment: There is a reason I am here.  If you can't give me the answer, just say so.

Comment: The answer is right above. You get from your database either true or false right? So just get that value and set it to $scope.user.admin = yourDatabaseTable.yourDatabaseColumnValue. It is not difficult. Or just put your whole code, I'll give you exact answer! In your example there is no database.

Comment: I've updated my original posting with the relevant code.  userList is a json response from a rest call.