# AngularJs + select2 - empty option added

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

Ever since I upgraded from AngularJS 1.3.15 to 1.4.8 I'm getting an empty option added to all my select2 uses.

I've tried what is suggested here: [Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)
and in other questions, but couldn't make it work for me.

Here is a plunkr of my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/zrYCDbtSVHNt3tRZsQza?p=preview

As you can see, an empty option is added, after selecting any of the 2 values there, the empty option disappears.

The relevant HTML:

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="cqData.dataObjects.Mode.Value">
    <option value="structured" localize>Structured Query</option>
    <option value="advanced" localize>Advanced Query</option>
</select>
```

P.S. I know ui-select2 is deprecated, but its an existing project and I'm unable at the moment to upgrade it.

Comment: if you update select2 and ui-select2 (not to ui-select )it works  http://plnkr.co/edit/8WUPObf57WjhcY5ZbEfV?p=preview .

Comment: @koox00 Awesome! You know how to fix the errors it throws to the console?

Comment: @koox00 it gives me a lot more errors when I update the references in my project, including some modals that stop working, probably it all comes down to solving the error it throws in the plunkr though

Comment: I've updated my plunker using angular 1.4.7 doesn't have that blank option. but I think if you are going to update you have to update everything

Comment: @koox00 thanks! Seems I'll be stuck with 1.4.7 until I have time to upgrade to ui-select library.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set default value in controller like this:

```
$scope.cqData.dataObjects.Mode.Value = $scope.cqData.dataObjects.Mode[0].Value;
```

Its working fine.

Comment: How does that answer my question? It isn't relevant how I initialize the ngModel, as long as I do.